# Политика относительно всеобъемлющих вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, хэшкод, тематика, миграция

По-моему, настало времени определиться с политикой относительно вопросов, которые ни в каком приближении не соответствуют правилам английского Stack Overflow. Положим, есть спорные запреты вроде вопросов о выборе библиотеки, но с ХэшКода унаследованы вопросы, которые ни в каком виде под определение QA не подходят, например, открытые обсуждения, на которые нельзя дать явный ответ.

- [Встречи участников Хэшкод в реале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174810/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%a5%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5)
- [Как учить ребенка программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)
- [Вопрос о работе программиста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90010/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)
- [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/92747/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c)
- [Программист без спец. образования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47811/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)
- [Будущие перспективы программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)
- [Имеет ли смысл ребенка учить ООП?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144983/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f)
- и так далее

Какие планы относительно этих вопросов?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть комментарий @Nicolas Chabanovsky на этот счет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопросы, не соответствующие правилам, должны быть удалены. Stack Overflow изначально создавался с идеей сделать из неструктурированных обсуждений базу знаний, поэтому должны остаться только вопросы, соответствующие формату.

Хотя обсуждения могут казаться ценными как наследие ХэшКода, их всё равно нельзя оставлять даже в закрытом или заблокированном виде, потому что вновь пришедшие пользователи будут ориентироваться на самые популярные вопросы, чтобы понять, какие вопросы на сайте уместны. Гораздо лучше, если новички увидят среди самых популярных вопросов те, которые соответствуют формату QA.

Через подобную "утрату" уже проходил большой Stack Overflow. Самые популярные вопросы на нём удалены. Настало время провести чистку и здесь.

Comment: А может лучше следовать здравому смыслу (т.е. форум долже быть  прежде всего **интересен** участникам)   -- лично я против удаления как существующих, так и еще не заданных "непрофильных", но интересных вопросов.

Comment: @avp Stack Overflow — это НЕ форум, а QA. Это миссия SE, если угодно. Загляните в [Тур](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) наконец — это один из первых абзацев, и на протяжении всего тура объясняется разница. Если гоняться за популярностью, можно начать постить фотки с котиками. Всему своё место.

Comment: я все это читал,  и такая позиция мне давно известна. Неужели Вы серьезно думаете, что ее в глубине души разделяют многие (еще оставшиеся здесь) профессионалы (вероятно, как и я лишенные в силу ряда причин постоянного полноценного профессионального (а именно -- программистского) общения, скажем, на работе)?  Мне кажется, что нет, вот и уходят, поскольку, на самом деле, ответы на большинство вопросов  это лишь повод пообщаться (и вовсе не с автором вопроса) в надежде, что возникнет действительно интересное обсуждение.

Comment: @avp Для общения в менее формальном формате всё ещё существуют программистские форумы: Винград, РСДН, ЛОР и другие. Я уж молчу про Хабрахабр и прочие блогоподобные ресурсы, где общение слабо ограничивается. Приходить на СО за форумным общением — это весьма странная затея. Была попытка с Not-Programming-Related (или как его там) / Programmers, но она провалилась, и ресурс сделал разворот на 180 градусов, там теперь 50% вопросов закрывается, и всё протухло. Немного свободнее общение на Метах, и там и правда появляются "топы", но сетовать на судьбу вечно невозможно, тоже надоедает.

Comment: @avp Не могу сказать, что я в восторге от политики СО (скажу откровенно, по возможности я вовсе активно сопротивляюсь некоторым правилам), но у сайта есть формат, который и привёл его к успеху. Попытки идти против провалились. / Для вопросов про выбор нужного из списка возможного существует и активно развивается Slant. Для форумного общения я очень рассчитываю на новое детище Джеффа — Discourse. А на СО путь будут вопросы и ответы.

Comment: (не пойму, почему набираемый текст `@Athari` в начале комментария у меня исчезает) @Athari, в данном случае я не столько сетую на судьбу, сколько забочусь об авторах **будущих вопросов**. Возможно я заблуждаюсь, но мне кажется, что еще пару лет назад **уровень ответов** был повыше. Про разные форумы --  Хэшкод  (теперь SO) реально интересен широтой спектра вопросов и частотой их появления (а Хабр слишком снобистский ресурс).

Comment: @avp Уведомления всегда отправляются авторам вопроса и ответа, поэтому СО считает их избыточными и удаляет. Иногда это мешается, но разрабы против изменения. / Раньше трава была зеленее. Сначала фидошники выли, что на форумах одни идиоты, общаться стало негде. Потом форумные жители выли, что вебдванольные блоги ведут идиоты, общаться негде. Теперь блогеры воют, что в соц. сетях одни идиоты, общаться негде. Дальше будет ещё хуже. :) / Уровень вопросов и ответов на СО снижается, да. Но если позволить писать неформатные посты, то будет ещё хуже и гораздо быстрее.

Comment: @avp Эксперт где-то в чате высказывал мнение, что он за более широкую тематику на РУ.СО. И при общении с ним на Хабре у меня сложилось впечатление, что он несколько оптимистично оценивает вписывание ХК в строгий формат СО. Поэтому есть вероятность, что отношение к неформатным вопросам будет мягче, чем на большом СО. Впрочем, Эксперту вряд ли дадут единолично властвовать сайтом и определять тематику. Скорее всего, происходят какие-то обсуждения по этим вопросам. Так или иначе, ждём ответа Николаса.

Answer (score 8):

На англоязычном SO вопросы, которые могут испортить сайт как Q&A, выносятся на другие сайты сети Stack Exchange. Например, вопросы о review кода выносятся на code review, вопросы о рабочем процессе выносятся на programmers, а администрирование — на superuser.

Русскоязычных аналогов этих сайтов нет, поэтому ни мигрирование, ни массовое удаление не являются правильным способом борьбы с такими вопросами. Полагаю, нужно две политики

1. Для вопиюще неформатных существующих вопросов использовать **удаление**. Это жёсткая мера, учитывая, что на подобные вопросы где-то могут быть ссылки на других ресурсах. Применять её нужно только тогда, когда количество людей, которые захотели бы вернуться на эту страницу, однажды посетив её, оценивается как где-то не отличающееся от нуля.
2. Для всех остальных неформатных существующих вопросов **помечать их как исторически ценные**.

Answer (score 5):

Я за либеральную политику обычного IT форума и здравый смысл. Нет никакой пользы от удаления вопросов из базы под предлогом того что они не соответствуют каким-то воображаемым критериям чьей-то левой пятки. Кому в здравом уме мешает вопрос "Как учить ребенка программировать?" или "Зачем вы здесь?".

Сколько правил сюда не вводи эта штуковина все равно на деле просто представляет из себя обычный пропиетарный форумный скрипт из которого надо насильственно удалять разве что совсем неформатные сообщения и рекламу, чтобы не мешать другим людям болтать между собой об их делах так как им заблагорассудится.

По поводу идеи об успехе за счет строгой выдержки Q&A формата, то она скорее всего ложна. Навряд ли случайный собеседник на том конце провода может разбираться в проблеме лучше чем оригинальный автор очередной программы в которой снова что-то пошло не так.

И да я из тех людей кто считает почти все попытки править уже прочитаный больше месяца назад текст легкой формой паранойи, ОКР или необоснованной, ложной, навязчивой идеей.

Comment: Идея и успех SO не в том, что конкретному человеку помогли ответить на вопрос, а в том, что, когда вы пишите в гугле "How can I do X in Y?" в топе выдачи будет SO. И хороший ответ на хороший вопрос поможет  тысячам людей, даже не зарегистрированных на SO.

Comment: Но я так же против агрессивной политики к старым постам. Это как-никак наследие ХэшКода созданное в теплом ламповом сообществе.

Comment: В итоге важно соблюсти баланс, чтобы не потерять старожилов, но и поддерживать качество контента на высоком уровне.

Comment: @Nofate У нормальных старожилов есть 2К репы, которые дают им свободно наслаждаться просмотром любых удалённых вопросов. :)

Answer (score 5):

Не стоит, не думая перенимать политику SO -- это другой сайт, совсем другой масштаб. Вещи, которые работают и даже необходимы для сайта с 10 миллионами вопросов, могут быть совсем не обязательны и даже вредны для сайта, где их в сотни раз меньше.

Например, можно сохранить тематику ХэшКода, которая обычно публикуется на Server Fault, Unix & Linux, Code Review, Programmers, Database Administrators, etc других сайтах StackExchange сети.

Каждую категорию вопросов можно рассмотреть отдельно на предмет приносят ли такие вопросы больше пользы или вреда:

- являются ли сами вопросы/ответы полезными (прямо сейчас для человека, который задал вопрос и на большем сроке для посетителей из поисковика)
- какие люди на подобные вопросы отвечают, например, используются ли факты, опыт или ответы -- дело вкуса.

О всех примерах: если подобных вопросов относительно не слишком много, то можно оставить как есть -- не нужно удалять.

По конкретным примерам:

- [Встречи участников Хэшкод в реале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174810/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%a5%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5)

  на Мете вполне можно такой вопрос оставить (c обсуждением в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462) если необходимо)
- [Как учить ребенка программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

  вопрос полезный, хотя конечно слишком обширный, но до тех пор пока подобные вопросы не заполонят домашнюю страницу, не вижу пользы от запрета
- [Вопрос о работе программиста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90010/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

  нормальный вопрос: можно кратко ответить, используя знания и опыт работы в разработке ПО
- [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/92747/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c)

  для Меты вполне подходит
- [Программист без спец. образования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47811/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

  вопрос простой, но кому-то может пригодиться
- [Будущие перспективы программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

  вопрос демонстрирует типичные заблуждения с этой темой и уже поэтому является интересным -- плюс ещё есть пара полезных для новичков ответов
- [Имеет ли смысл ребенка учить ООП?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144983/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f)

  также нормальный вопрос по "мягкой" теме

Повторюсь: вопросы явно полезны/интересны и если они не вытесняют другие более подходящие по тематике вопросы (в рамках английского SO), то стоит их оставить. В данный момент только [60 вопроса в день на Stack Overflow на русском](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) так что проблемы с засильем вопросов не по теме я не вижу.

Comment: Про различия в масштабах говорить некорректно: в сети Stack Exchange есть общие правила, которые применяются и на 10-миллионном SO, и на только-только запустившейся альфе с 10-ю вопросами. / И речь совсем не про SF, SU, CR, DBA и прочие, тематики, которые прекрасно вписываются в QA (хотя лично я предпочёл бы RU.SF и RU.SU отдельно). Если бы вопросов про обучение была пара штук, то шут с ними, но ведь их тьма тьмущая, и их невозможно систематизировать, и каждый новый юзер будет приходить и снова задавать тот же самый вопрос: то ли у него ситуация чуть другая, то ли данные через год устарели.

Comment: Миссия СО — в первую очередь не помогать одному конкретному человеку, а помогать всем, кто столкнётся с похожей проблемой. Именно этой цели следует строгий формат QA. Вопросы же в духе "Учить ли МНЕ язык X" совершенно невозможно применить даже в немного изменившейся ситуации. Ответы на эти вопросы очень быстро устаревают, поэтому будет накапливаться огромное количество балласта. Подобных вопросов уже куча, и их будет всё больше и больше. Их даже как дубликат закрыть нельзя. / Гоняться за популярностью — грех. Давайте постить котиков, они популярнее этих ваших языков программирования.

Comment: @Athari: в рамках движка, каждое сообщество свободно выбирать какие правила с каким рвением усиливать. Нужно голову использовать и понимать что 7.2 вопроса в день -- не является тьма тьмущей. Приведённые вопросы не являются образцовыми, и не являются вопросами строго по теме, **если** популярность сайта возрастёт и они превратятся в действительную проблему, то конечно их нужно закрывать. Про "котиков" -- не надо чепуху пороть: если *одно* правило не работает это ещё не значит что надо *все* правила отменять.

Comment: Количество вопросов в день — не самоцель. Если на сайте будет в больших концентрациях поститься мусор, то это наоборот отпугнёт вменяемый народ, которому не захочется искать жемчужины в навозе. На http://security.stackexchange.com 7 вопросов в день, а это даже не бета. На http://ux.stackexchange.com — 6.7. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com — 6.6. http://dba.stackexchange.com — 8.9. Это всё успешные сайты, вышедшие из беты в большой мир.

Comment: @Athari: Не нужно искажать мои слова (1) про миссию: важен как отдельный человек прямо сейчас так и будущие посетители из поисковика (2) про вопросы: количество *полезных* вопросов с *хорошими* ответами безусловно важно -- человек не может найти ответ в гугле, если вопрос уже не задан и отвечен. А чтобы задать вопрос или ответить на вопрос, человек должен знать о существовании сайта. Поэтому на начальном этапе можно "мягкие вопросы" особо строго не отсеивать, если они могу помочь повысить известность.

Comment: Если говорить про начальный этап, то ещё даже не разосланы уведомления с Зоны 51. То есть бета-то ещё условно-открытая. Сюда ещё должны понабежать сотни подписавшихся под RU.SO на Зоне 51.

Answer (score 4):

В StackOverflow есть специальный режим "Вопрос не считается соответствующим тематике сайта, но оставлен как исторически ценный". Для таких вопросом не работают новые ответы, комментарии, голосование - он превращается просто в статичнескую страницу.

Comment: Куча вопросов в этом режиме какое-то время назад были беспощадно выпилены. :) Если у вас есть 10К на СО, то можете посмотреть и убедиться в масштабах чистки.

Comment: @Athari, такие вопросы восстанавливают (конечно, если там что-то большое и интересное) и делают заблокированными (как в этом описании).

Comment: @Athari, предлагаете следовать их примеру?

Comment: @_Vi Вы слишком оптимистичны. Выпилено большое количество не только забавных, но и реально полезных вопросов. И их не восстанавливают. [Most useful free .NET libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/662956) (+687), [What are some funny loading statements to keep users amused?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/182112) (+597), [Where can one find free software icons / images?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139944) (+597), [Great programming quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/58640) (+531)... мне продолжать?

Comment: @Nofate Своё мнение я раскрыл в своём ответе и комментариях под ним. Если вкратце, то да.

Comment: @Athari, Я думаю, дейвовать нужно также в качественном смысле, но с другими количественными характеристиками (больше заблокированных "исторических", меньше удалённых). В любом случае сначала можно просто закрыть те вопросы.

Comment: Я в целом не люблю совсем удалённый content (поэтому всегда создаю локальные копии, если что-то нужно), ни на SE, ни в википедии, ни на Github'е и т.д.. Часто "слабое" удаление (закрыть изменения + спрятать из поиска (в том числе google), может ещё требовать капчу для просмотра) уже решает проблему, но не создаёт сломанного (404) веба.

Comment: Также при работе над такими вопросами нужно следить, чтобы они не всплывали на заглавную страницу (как например если добавлять в них какое-либо сообщение при помощи правок).

Comment: @_Vi Я тоже против перманентного удаления. В случае СО эта проблема решается: достаточно заработать 10К репы на СО или 2К репы на бете. Если первое в меру сложно, то второе достигается без проблем. Да и Wayback Machine никто не отменял. Думаю, весь хэшкод сохранён. / Основная проблема с заблокированными "исторически важными" вопросами — это что они выводятся первыми при сортировке по голосам. Новички будут смотреть на эти вопросы и думать, что сайт именно для подобного контента. В долгосрочной перспективе наличие неформатных вопросов вредно.

Comment: @Athari, У меня "репа" везде медленно растёт, до viewdelete ещё нигде не доросла (лет за 5).

Comment: @Athari, заблокированность вопроса разве не влияет на то выводится ли он в каких-либо списках или не выводится? Также отметки "[закрыт]" должны  намекать, что такое не проходит. Эффект на новичков, думаю, сильно зависит от внешнего вида, наличия в списках, порядка сортировки и т.д. На них и нужно воздействовать. "Окончательное, фактическое" удаление уместно для спама и по решению суда.

Comment: @_Vi Если вопрос заблокирован, он всё равно выводится во всех списках и поиске. Разве что на главную не попадает, но кому до неё дело? Намекать-то отметки могут, но наличие шикарных онтопичных вопросов в топе гораздо вероятнее вдохновит на написание правильных вопросов. Если в топе оффтопик, то возникает закономерный вопрос: "Может, не успеют быстро закрыть, и все желающие успеют наотвечать?" / Если не брезговать, то можно добыть репу достаточно быстро. Последние полторы тысячи репы до 10К я получил жёстким repwhoring'ом — противно, но результат того стоил. :)

Answer (score 4):

ХэшКод изначально задумывался как Stack Overflow на русском, и был создан именно потому, что Stack Exchange не планировала его запуск (если быть честным, Stack Exchange тогда еще не существовало). Мы изначально старались следовать идеологии в Stack Overflow: удалять вопросы на вроде “Как стать программистом за один час?”, избегать грубости, закрывать дискуссионные вопросы, переносить информацию из комментариев в ответы и вопросы и т. д.

Нам не всегда удавалось достичь желаемого. В случаях, когда сообщество было явно против наших действий, например, мы закрывали вопросы, а вскоре пользователи переоткрывали его, мы старались быть демократичными и следовать базовым правилам принятии решения удалить вопрос или нет. В большинстве случаев достаточно ответить на [несколько вопросов](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

1. Соответствует ли вопрос тематике форума описанной в FAQ?
2. Будет ли вопрос хорошо принят сообществом, получил ли он достаточно голосов “за” и ответов?
3. Смогут ли пользователи повысить свою квалификацию после прочтения данного вопроса и ответов на него?

Конечно же, это базовые принципы, но в купе с удалением дискуссий, совсем простых вопросов (например, “Как создать программу под андроид?”), домашних заданий без решения и прочих вопросов, на которые никто из профессионального сообщества не хочет отвечать, получается достаточно мощный фильтр, отсекающих большинство вопросов, которым не место на Stack Overflow.

ХэшКод не имел всех необходимых средств для передачи полного контроля над содержим сообществу, а модераторы могли что-то пропустить. Как результат, действительно, есть ряд вопросов и ответов, которые следует удалить. Администрация ХэшКода проводила подобные “чистки” раз в пол года (после сессий). Но опять же, мы могли что-то пропустить.

Набор разрешенным тем на Stack Overflow на русском (должен) может быть отличен от Stack Overflow на английском, потому что:

- Stack Overflow на русском - это не Stack Overflow на английском, это не просто другое сообщество, это разные культуры.
- Stack Overflow на русском - молодое сообщество, у нас нет сайтов спутников (они были, но были не эффективны). Например, как результат, вопросы касающиеся системного администрирования, не разрешенные на Stack Overflow на английском, разрешены в нашем сообществе.
- …

Таким образом, по моему мнению, мы - это сообщество профессиональных программистов и энтузиастов программирования. Проект Stack Overflow на русском про, исключительно, прикладные, исключительно, вопросы и ответы. В то же время, мы сами выбираем темы вопросов, по которым мы будем отвечать (администрирование серверов?). Это наша общая миссия, вместе, определить, какие вопросы могут быть полезны и интересны коллегам. Причем без каких-либо оглодок на Stack Overflow на английском, но в рамках модели вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow.

Comment: Если не изменяет память, вопросы, закрытые ромбовыми модераторами, могут быть переоткрыты только ромбовыми модераторами. И, подозреваю, если возникает война закрытий-переоткрытий вопроса, то это высвечивается на радарах ромбовых модераторов. (Наверное, то же верно для удаления, не интересовался — в любом случае там войнам возникнуть сложнее, потому что на удалённое ещё надо найти прямую ссылку.) То есть на Stack Overflow не может возникнуть ситуация, когда администрация приняла решение относительно уместности вопроса, а пользователи перекрыли мнение администрации.

Comment: @Athari Верно относительно удаления, но не относительно закрытия. Вопрос, закрытый модератором, может быть открыт рядовыми пользователями с надлежащей репутацией. В этом можно убедиться экспериментально, или [на примере](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/251758/revisions) (Robert Harvey закрыл, пять участников переоткрыли).

Comment: @pizza А, значит, ещё заблокировать надо. Блокировка точно только у ромбов, у простых смертных в дополнение к закрытию только смехотворная "защита".

Answer (score 4):

Выскажусь и я. Все таки имею право на специальное мнение, поскольку:

1. я один из ветеранов Хэшкода (как никак скоро 4 года стукнет)
2. в том числе и один из [ветеранов самого оригинального SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472270/barmaley)
3. модератор на Хэшкод
4. половина вопросов вынесенных ТС на обсуждение либо заданы были мной, либо были отвечены мной.

1) Я бы не стал ставить знак равенства между SO и Хэшкодом. SO это SO - там все таки немножко по другому. Там больше технического, нежели человеческого. Так что не вижу противоречия в том, если будут немного разные правила. В конце-концов если кого-то не устраивают правила русского SO - может идти в англоязычный SO - колхоз дело добровольное.

2) Популярность ресурса обеспечивается в первую очередь траффиком, конечно траффик должен быть полезным и я искренне не понимаю почему вопрос типа: [Будущие перспективы программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - чем то вредит ресурсу?

3) Не очень понимаю, почему скороспелые мальчики, которые в ресурсе всего то 1.5 месяца не знающие историю развития ресурса так торопятся что-то поломать? Ломать то не строить. Вы сначала постройте что-то, а уж потом ломайте.

P.S. Возможно я где-то слегка грубоват, зато говорю правду.

Comment: "Скороспелые мальчики", как вы выразились, тоже ветераны на Stack Overflow с пятилетним стажем, тысячами ревью и сотней флагов. / *Сейчас* этот сайт — часть Stack Exchange, а не Сети Знаний. С соответствующими последствиями. / "Не нравится — иди на все четыре стороны" — последний аргумент. Я-то уйду, а вот те, кто не знает английский, могут хотеть сайт, сравнимый по качеству с англоязычным SO. Куда им податься, если вы за разведение флуда? / Траффика предостаточно. Мы по траффику обходим PT.SO, между прочим (в 2 раза больше просмотров, примерно столько же вопросов). Сейчас ещё рассылка прошла.

Comment: Речь не об этом. А о том, что нельзя бездумно переносить опыт большого SO на русский стек.

Comment: @Athari Как правильно написано в одном из ответов выше, у оригинального SO есть множество спутников, на которые переносятся непрофильные темы. А у русскоязычного SO таких спутников нет, поэтому жесткие правила SO принципиально не могут применяться к ru.SO. Это не значит, что можно устраивать помойку - это значит только то, что нужно быть *немного* мягче и пользоваться головой

Comment: @dmi7ry Речь не про вопросы, которые уместны на спутниках, а про вопросы, которые запрещены на всей сети SE.

Answer (score 3):

По моему, для дискуссионных вопросов самое теперь место **в чате**. Полагаю, для каждого из таких следует создавать просто отдельную комнату.

Насколько я понимаю, комнаты имеют какое-то время жизни, по крайней мере, на период наличия активности в них, поэтому все, что требует обсуждения, все кто желает высказаться по поводу вопроса, будут иметь на это возможности, да и принцип Q&A в таком случае будет сохранен.

Сам переход от вопроса к чату - узкое место, не могу сейчас предложить адекватный переход, т.к. не нимел еще повода использовать этот инструмент.

Могу только предположить, что дискуссия может начинаться **с вопроса** (о котором пишет @_Vi), а с разрастанием к-ва комментариев - переноситься в чат. Какая-то тезисная часть дискуссии при этом может оседать в теле **исходного вопроса**. Ссылка на комнату, конечно - тоже.

Конечно, роль "зачинщика" при этом должна бы быть более привилегированной, т.к. он должен иметь возможность выносить в свой вопрос на SO адекватные тезисы, но, думаю, с этим могут помочь и сами участники. Можно бы было вообще делать такие вопросы общими.

Comment: Вы вообще о чём? Мета по определению предназначена для подобных обсуждений. Жёсткие критерии QA на Мету не распространяются. Что касается чата, то обе известные мне комнаты протухли, там активность по нулям: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21564/stack-overflow-in-russian-translation и http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: Мета, по формату - такой же QA, как и SO. По поводу "обе комнаты потухли", то на chat.stackexchange.com я, честно говоря, их даже никогда не наблюдал (даже не знал, что их было 2). Собственно, для того, чтобы не тухли и предлагаю держать связь комнаты с исходным вопросом (место встреч).

Comment: 1. На мете допускаются вопросы без чёткого ответа, открытые обсуждения. 2. На мете голосование используется для выражения мнения, а не только отражения корректности и качества. 3. На мете вопросы не обязаны быть вопросами, они могут быть предложениями, обсуждениями, уведомлениями. И так далее.

Comment: @Athari, не имею ничего против меты, я предлагаю как раз формат общения на SO. Сам вопрос можно держать где-угодно.