# Как редактировать справку?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

Справка является (или должна являться) частью сайта, которая может редактироваться сообществом. По крайней мере участниками с высокой репутацией.

**На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?**
**https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic**

Самый главный топик справки относительно тематики ru.stackoverflow, на который ссылается и остальная справка и комментарии в проверке. Сейчас туда залит перевод соответствующего топика из справки к Мете (почему? - отдельный вопрос, ну да ладно). Не важно откуда он взят, смысл в том, что он не соответствует ни тематике Хэшкода, ни тематике stackoverflow.

Не умаляя заслуг переводчика относительно других страниц справки, данная страница должна быть модифицирована. Даже пока идут дискуссии относительно вопросов на [всеобъемлющие темы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/34/) и формируется редакционная политика ru.SO важно дать возможность сообществу редактировать справку.

В качестве начальной точки отсчета (не знаю каков механизм для редактирования справки и есть ли он вообще):
2k репутации - редактирование справки.
5к репутации - принятие правок справки.
10к репутации - создание новых страниц справки.

С другой стороны, afaik, справка может редактироваться только модераторами (на бете выборов кстати вряд ли стоит ждать, да?). Значит как альтернатива должен быть механизм обсуждения текста справки, принятия его на Мете и внесения изменений.

---

**N.B.** В любом случае на данный момент необходимо зафиксировать то, что вопросы должны касаться программирования и администрирования (напомню, что Руткод стал частью Хэшкода), а никак не рекламы и вакансий в SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В текущей реализации сайта, создавать новые страницы справочного центра могут только сотрудники компании. Любую страницу справочного центра можно модифицировать, если при создании/правке она была отмечена специальным флагом. Изменения в такие страницы могут вносить только модераторы или сотрудники.

Как мне кажется, отличным местом для [обсуждения перевода является Мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/107/). Предлагаю напрямую править ответ, таким образом любой желающий сможет поучаствовать в переводе той или иной страницы.

---

На данный момент говорить о выборах чуть-чуть преждевременно. В то же время, чтобы форум был как можно более демократичным, мы предложили продолжить быть модераторами коллегам, которых [выбрало сообщество в 2013 году](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213/).

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(перенес из другого вопроса, здесь этот ответ более уместен)</sub>

Правки в разделы справки можно вносить опосредованно, через сообщения на Мете. Поскольку это одни из самых важных документов, то даже peer review, как с правками сообщений или описаний меток, здесь недостаточно. То есть, для принятия решения нужно мнение не фиксированного числа проверяющих (обычно 2-3), а *максимального числа* заинтересованных участников.

В случае опечатки решение достаточно очевидно. Но вы можете предлагать и более существенную переработку текста. Если предлагаемая правка приближает документ к достижению его цели — вероятно, она будет одобрена сообществом и принята администрацией.