# Уточнение предыдущего сообщения

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Если на мой вопрос уже ответили, но у меня остались некоторые вопросы к автору ответа, но он не отвечает, можно ли создать новый вопрос, и в нем расписать проблему?

Comment: Да, можно, но обязательно нужно дать ссылку на прошлый вопрос. А еще вопрос должен соответстовать требованиям. У вас уже 9 вопросов и довольно много минусов. Чтобы не повторять ошибок, давайте вместе подумаем, как вам задать вопрос в хорошей форме.

Comment: Не об этом ли речь идет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443605/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94#comment470033_443610

Comment: @NickVolynkin Он самый) Минусы были по началу, в основном из за того что не знал золотого правила - "Попробовал, не получилось, пиши на SO".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если после получения ответа у вас остались недопонимания именно по теме уже заданного вопроса, лучшим способом будет обновления вашего вопроса или уточняющего комментария автору ответа.

Если у вас появились дополнительные вопросы относительно описанной в вашем вопросе проблемы, пожалуйста, опубликуйте новый вопрос, добавив ссылку на предыдущий, для того, чтобы отобразить контекст.

***Не стоит** задавать дополнительные вопросы в комментариях к ответу.*