# Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Для рассуждения о причинах закрытия вопросов и, более, их удаления я хотел бы рассмотреть проблему создания оптимального источника знаний.

#### Stack Overflow на русском как источник знаний

**Проблема шума**

Представим, что Stack Overflow еще не запущен. В своей работе мы столкнулись с задачей, решения которой не знаем. Как же быть?

1. Если мы работаем в компании, состоящей более чем из одного человека, можно попробовать найти ответ среди коллег. Данная ситуация вполне типична для больших компаний, подобных Motorola. Работая в большой компании, столкнувшись с неразрешимой проблемой, мы первым делом были бы направлены руководителем к человеку, который, скорее всего, знает ответ. В компании такие знатоки имели звание “старший программист подразделения”.
2. Если возможности задать вопрос знающему коллеге нет, то, скорее всего, мы зададим вопрос сообществу на одном из форумов (напомню, Stack Overflow еще не запущен).

Первый подход с большой вероятностью закончится успешно, так что давайте рассмотрим второй. С какими проблемами мы сталкиваемся, задавая вопрос на стандартом форуме? Хочу выделить несколько основных, на мой взгляд, проблем, которые препятствуют быстрому получению ответа (да и вообще, желанию общаться на форумах):

- критика;
- дискуссии;
- непрофессиональность участников.

На самом деле этих причин намного больше. Большенство из них можно охарактеризовать одним словом - **шум**. Если мы задаем какой-то сложный вопрос, на который однозначно не найдем ответ самостоятельно, то, возможно, такой подход хоть и не оптимален, но терпим. В случае же ежедневных рутинных задач силы, потраченные на обсуждение проблемы на дискуссионном форуме, оправдываются очень редко. От части поэтому специалисты, особенно работающие в области информационных технологий, предпочитают искать информацию через поисковик до того, как задать вопрос. Но проблема “шума” в случае поиска не становится менее критичной, так как прежде чем найти “истину” (решение проблемы), нам необходимо прочитать огромное количество сообщений, не относящихся к сути вопроса.

**Проблема непрерывного обучения**

Как мне кажется, становясь специалистом, среднестатистический разработчик продолжает оттачивать свои навыки не по книгам, как было в начале карьеры, а с использованием примеров кода. Согласитесь, ведь намного проще найти пример использования библиотеки, а затем сделать по аналогии? Таким образом мы можем сэкономить много времени. Более того, мы все учимся непрерывно в процессе решения повседневных задач, задавая вопросы на форумах или находя ответы через поисковик.

---

Представьте, а что если каким-либо образом убрать весь ненужный шум из дискуссий на форумах (то есть всю информацию, которая не относится напрямую к вопросу: колкости, шутки, разговоры за жизнь и т. д.) и в добавок структурировать информацию таким образом, чтобы она не уступала по качеству и информативности примерам из официальной документации, то есть представить ее в виде “проблема - решение”. Не правда ли, здорово?

Таким образом, *Stack Overflow на русском* в первую очередь - это *инструмент*, позволяющий быстро получить знания без лишнего шума в формате “проблема (вопрос) - решение (ответ)”.

#### Какие вопросы не стоит закрывать?

Учитывая сказанное выше, давайте рассмотрим, какие вопросы являются тематическими для сообщества. В самой общей формулировке можно сказать, что:

> Любой прикладной вопрос по программированию или системному администрированию, на который можно дать однозначно верный ответ, а также вопросы по программированию или системному администрированию, читая которые можно быстро обучиться чему-то новому, будут тематическими для сообщества.

Стоит уточнить, что:

> Все вопросы и ответы должны быть либо посвящены детальному рассмотрению какой-либо конкретной проблемы, либо представлять информацию о проблеме в наиболее кратком, но достаточном для понимания объеме.

#### Различие в восприятии вопросов знатоками и новичками

**Простые вопросы**

Скорее всего, мало кто возразит, что знатоки и новички по-разному воспринимают вопросы и ответы. Так, например, то, что тривиально для знатока, зачастую вызывает сложность у новичка. К тому же сам процесс поиска информации - это отдельный навык, который также вырабатывается со временем. Как результат, некоторые пользователи спрашивают, на первый взгляд знатока, настолько простые вопросы, что хочется отправить их в поисковик.

*Как же такое поведение выглядит со стороны новичка, только присоединившегося к сообществу?*

Если кратко, заносчиво и вульгарно.

*Как же рекомендовано поступать в таких случаях?*

Дать минимальный достаточный ответ. Как уже говорилось ранее, Stack Overflow нужен для быстрого обучения чему-либо. Вполне вероятно, что аналогичный простой вопрос возникнет у вашего *квалифицированного в другой области* коллеги, когда он решит исследовать новую для себя сферу профессиональной деятельности. Отвечая на базовые вопросы, мы на основе своего опыта даем краткий экскурс в проблематику.

Если посмотреть на пользу ответа на простой вопрос, можно заметить, что она будет как минимум не меньше (по количеству людей, которым помог ваш ответ), чем у сложного вопроса. Новичков всегда больше, чем профессионалов, а их вопросы схожи (все изучают языки по одним и тем же книгам и сталкиваются с одними и теми же проблемами).

**Слишком простые вопросы, для меня**

Немаловажным является наблюдение, когда простой вопрос получает хороший ответ, но закрывается другими пользователями, причем безусловно обладающими необходимой привилегией для принятия правильного решения о закрытии. Анализируя ситуацию, мы пришли к выводу, что если простой вопрос интересен знатоку, то он с радостью на него ответит. Как нам кажется, причиной тому является то, что когда-то давно, в процессе изучения, знаток сам сталкивался с подобной задачей и нашел интересное для себя решение, которым он хочет поделиться с сообществом. Как уже упоминалось выше, такие вопросы могут быть крайне полезными для коллег, которые только начинают изучать предметную область, как для новичков, так и для профессионалов.

Можно утверждать, *не бывает простых вопросов*, которые следовало бы закрывать/удалять, если они соответствуют [правилам форума](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), а также при условии наличия в сообществе знатоков, которые хотели бы ответить.

**Всеобъемлющие вопросы**

Рассмотрим наиболее крайний вопрос: “Что нужно знать начинающему Java-программисту?”. На первый взгляд, ответ на подобный вопрос будет либо слишком короткий (например, нужно знать язык), либо слишком длинный и от части зависящий от мнения. Но если углубиться в рассуждения, то можно заметить, что на подобный вопрос существует прекрасный и полезный ответ.

*Как можно ответить на вопрос “Что нужно знать начинающему Java-программисту?” с пользой для сообщества?*

Данным вопросом задастся человек, новы для языка Java. Это может быть как новичок (например, студент технического вуза), так и специалист ИТ (например, системный администратор или тестировщик, который хочет переквалифицироваться в Java-программиста). Поставив себя на место человека, задающего подобный вопрос, с одной стороны, и учитывая формат сообщества, с другой стороны, можно описать критерии хорошего ответа на подобный вопрос.

- **Вопрос и ответы должны быть отмечены общими**. Таким образом сообщество сможет вносить правки при необходимости и избежать личных мнений.
- **Ответ на такой вопрос должен быть минимально допустимого размера**. Крайне нежелательно, если ответ будет более двух экранов текста. Отвечая, следует учитывать “приближение” (конкретику, с которой задается вопрос). С увеличением “приближения” мы ожидаем более развернутый ответ, и, наоборот, если задается общий вопрос, как в нашем примере, то и ответ должен иметь минимальное количество информации, но быть содержательным.
- **Ответ должен включать минимум текста и максимум ссылок**. Ответы на подобные вопросы можно сравнить с описаниями меток, в которых мы даем краткий словесный экскурс в проблематику, а затем дополняем его ссылками на последующее развернутое изучение.

Учитывая приведенные выше доводы, можно сказать, что при принятии решения о закрытии не следует руководствоваться тем, что вопрос “слишком простой” или “слишком общий”, так как по факту любой вопрос может быть принят сообществом, если он правильно сформулирован и есть как минимум один знаток, готовый на него ответить. Закрывая тему, мы говорим автору, что его вопрос не соответствует стандартам форума, что нет никого, кто бы мог исправить содержание сообщения, и более того, никто не собирается публиковать ответы. На наш взгляд, так стоит поступать с теми вопросами, которые нарушают идеологию проекта:

- вопросы с просьбами о завершении задач за автора, как учебных, так и рабочих;
- слишком локальные вопросы (например, вызванные опечаткой);
- вопросы вида “найди ошибку в моем коде” с условием, что они никак и никому, за исключением автора, не смогут помочь в будущем;
- вопросы-опросники.

Также не стоит жалеть вопросы, не удовлетворяющие стандартам качества проекта, то есть вопросы, плохо оформленные или плохо сформулированные, которые сообщество исправить не в силах.

Пожалуйста, помните, что каждый раз закрывая вопрос, вы говорите автору, что его вопросу, и от части самому автору, не место в нашем сообществе, как минимум, не в текущей форме. Тем самым вы лишаете сообщество альтернативного мнения в будущем, а отвергнутого автора - профессионального общения. Таким инструментом следует пользоваться крайне осмотрительно.

#### Какие вопросы стоит удалять вместо закрытия?

Некоторые вопросы мы рекомендуем удалять вместо закрытия. Существуют вопросы, на которые сообщество не может ответить в силу размера или отсутствия экспертизы. В этом случае стоит либо попросить коллегу или знакомого, который может ответить, но по каким-либо причинам еще не принимает участие в сообществе, поделиться знаниями, либо удалить такой вопрос. Так стоит поступать в особенности со старыми вопросами, для которых, очевидно, нет и в ближайшее время не будет качественного ответа. В удалении нет ничего плохого, наоборот, оно полезно сообществу - если вопрос действительно насущный, то рано или поздно он будет задан снова, но если вопрос “висит” без ответа, то наши коллеги раз за разом не находят решение на сайте, приходя из поисковика, и тем самым тратят драгоценное время.

#### Заключение

Формат вопросов и ответов по умолчанию подразумевает в себе две противоположных сущности: знатока и учащегося. Знатоку хочется, чтобы вопрос был как можно сложнее, ведь только в сложном вопросе он сможет показать все свои знания и умения. У новичков, однако, зачастую возникают вопросы средней сложности, на которые они хотят получить как можно более простой ответ, содержащий решение. Знаток же, скорее всего, ответит со знанием дела, развернуто и исчерпывающе, в результате чего у новичка появится не только ответ на его вопрос, но еще больше новых вопросов по теме. И это здорово, так как способствует профессиональному развитию.

Знатоки находятся в более выгодном положении, ведь именно они принимают решение о закрытии вопроса. Спешу заметить, что, будучи знатоком, принимать решение о закрытии или удалении следует с позиции новичка, а не знатока. Ведь ответы от человека, обладающего знаниями, призваны помочь именно тем, кто этими знаниями не владеет, то есть новичкам. Таким образом, нам, сообществу знатоков, не стоит шпынять новичков, то и дело закрывая вопрос как “не по теме” или с предлогом, что он “всеобъемлющий”. Вместо этого следует проявлять снисходительность к новичкам, как минимум на первых порах, как благодарность за их стремление к знаниям и в знак поддержки в их начинаниях.

Comment: Не возражаете, если я тут вставлю абзац про удаление спама и оскорблений?

Comment: Совершенно нет.

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky а делать тем участникам ruSO которые только начали учится а им с первого дня ставят минусы и закрываю их вопросы ?

Answer (score 11):

Откуда ни возьмись, на сайте возникает вопрос: "Как изучить Java?" Его не закрывают — все прониклись речью Николаса о *простых вопросах*.

Один юзер скажет: прочитай вот этот толстый талмуд по Java — вот истиный путь джедая. Лишь нюансы все познав, можно называть программистом Java себя.

Второй возразит: толстый талмуд — это для старпёров, современые люди изучают язык по тонким брошюркам "как изучить X за неделю", а остальное как-нибудь наберётся с опытом.

Набежит ещё три человека и накидают ссылок на свои любимые книжки: эта лучше! нет, эта лучше!

И вот у нас уже пять ответов и срач в комментариях.

Но тут приходит шестой юзер, и говорит, что главное — это вдохновление от процесса творения, что книжки — это, конечно, хорошо, но нужно писать то, что тебе нравится. И спрашивает автора вопроса: что же тебе, о новоиспечённый программист, нравится? И юзер отвечает: хочу ММОРПГ написать. Шестой юзер, издавая невнятные вопли, убегает в ужасе.

Тут на вечеринку заглядывает седьмой юзер, седой гейм-девелопер со стажем больше, чем возраст всех окружающих вместе взятых, познавший всё от тетриса до Assasin's Creed, и толкает вдохновенную речь: не нужно браться за великое, начни с малого, делай маленькие шажки, и придёшь к великому светлому будущему. И вот тебе, юзер, краткий маршрут.

Восьмой юзер и девятый юзер, заметив активную тему, влезают со своими предложениями: один говорит писать для одной мобильной платформы, а другой — для другой, и, перебивая друг друга, принимаются доказывать преимущества любимой оси в частности и перспективы разработки для мобилок в целом.

Приходит десятый юзер и называет всех идиотами: где же это видано — с игрушек начинать? Начинай, дорогой юзер, с веба. Сейчас всё там. И мобилки там. И будущее. Забудь про эти глупые игрушки, лучше веб попробуй.

Чтобы было веселее, одиннадцатый, двенадцатый и тринадцатый юзер принимаются доказывать достоинства C++ над тормозным Java, C# над отсталым Java и Scala над нефункциональным Java.

---

...И тут Николас просыпается в холодному поту и вспоминает, что на сайте Stack Overflow принято задавать чёткие вопросы, давать чёткие ответы, а флуд на пространные темы — это прерогатива чатов и традиционных форумов.

Можно спать спокойно: на Stack Overflow такой вопрос закроют максимум через час. И никаких тринадцати юзеров нет — это всё ночной кошмар.

Comment: А что _плохого_ в такой дискуссии? Откуда взяться холодному поту?

Comment: @VladD Проблема шума. См. оригинальный пост, собственно.

Comment: Если на вопрос нет однозначного ответа, то на него и не дадут однозначный ответ. Так что тут стоит ожидать «шум». Но такие — шумные — вопросы тоже нужны, раз люди их задают, и если уж на них отвечают, то являются онтопиком. А вот если на вопрос можно ответить более-менее однозначно, шум не нужен, да.

Comment: Четырнадцатый юзер(наглый приспешник старого доброго C) внезапно заходит [в беседу Java-господ](http://anticache.img0.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/java-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-921057.jpeg)

Comment: @VladD Stack Overflow позиционирует себя как сайт без шума, как инструмент эффективного получения знаний.

Comment: Позиционирует, да. Но посмотрите вопросы/ответы с наибольшим количеством голосов.

Comment: @VladD Вы будете утверждать, что лучше вопросы и ответы — с самым большим количеством голосов, и что они приводят к развитию сайта в нужном направлении?

Comment: @Athari: Раз за них голосуют, значит, они нравятся/нужны людям. А насчёт «нужного» направления не совсем понял: **кому** нужному? Юзерам? Да, они голосуют плюсиками.

Comment: @VladD юзеры будут голосовать плюсиками за "а какой ваш любимый анекдот java". igumnov выше уже 3 плюса за такое словил. так что, анекдоты теперь онтопик?

Comment: @VladD вот каноничный шумящий пост: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F. Пост - ни о чем. Ответы - ни о чем (лидирует ответ "делай что нравится"). Куча плюсов, никакой пользы.

Comment: @PashaPash: В рамках здравого смысла. Я, например, обожаю вот [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/276994) и ответы к нему.

Comment: @PashaPash: А по поводу Питона — почему? Хороший мотивирующий ответ. Мне бы так кто-то сказал в своё время. Немного офтопик, да.

Comment: А `// sometimes I believe compiler ignores all my comments` я бы напечатал на футболке.

Comment: То самое сладкое чувство когда толстый трололо комментарий победоносно набирает больше плюсов чем ответ.

Comment: @igumnov: Потому что такая дискуссия нуждается в оживляющей порции троллинга.

Comment: @VladD ответ хороший. вопрос плохой. потому что кроме одного хорошего ответа он вызвал пачку плохих и флуд. А вот в треде про комменты плохих ответов нет )

Comment: @PashaPash: Я всегда говорил: хороший ответ может спасти как угодно плохой вопрос.

Comment: @VladD Когда хороший ответ один, а мусора вокруг него много, весь смысл теряется.

Comment: @Athari: Ну, если ответ всплывёт наверх по голосам, всё хорошо. Разве нет?

Comment: @VladD Не факт, что этот ответ напишут, не факт, что быстро и вовремя, не факт, что он всплывёт, не факт, что потом не протухнет. Короче, слишком много "если".

Comment: @Athari: Ну, никто не спасёт вопрос — значит, можно его со спокойной совестью сносить. Я ж уже говорил, хороший вопрос или нет, зависит от наличия ответов. :-)

Comment: @VladD "Давайте пофлудим — авось среди флуда найдётся нормальное сообщение"?

Comment: @Athari: Как ни парадоксально звучит, да. В споре рождается что-то там такое.

Comment: Был взят пример, как можно более крайний. Все же, все целиком и полностью зависит от сообщества. Описание метки - это крайне общая информация, однако, проблем с ними мы не испытываем. Представим, что можно было бы давать описание комбинации меток, например, java и обучение. Такое описание как раз и было бы ответом на вопрос, "Что нужно знать начинающему Java-программисту?".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а что делать с описанием меток [java + c# + python + программирование + ПХП](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @VladD в споре про перспективы программирования не родилось ничего. Там есть ответ с пачкой плюсов. Но это нетехнический ответ на нетехническую проблему. Точно так же можно выбирать "пиво, под которое лучше код прет" - наверняка будет один заплюсованный ответ (и это будет не балтика). Упоминание "код" есть, прямое отношение к разработке есть. Оставляем?

Comment: @PashaPash: Для меня критерий простой: полезно ли программистам? А что за конкретная тема — как выбирать кефир для любителей ассемблера или подробности работы с Hibernate — не так уж важно. Хороший отрицательный ответ — тоже хороший ответ. Я, например, люблю начинать ответ с фразы «всё надо делать полностью по-другому», особенно на вопросы типа «какой регуляркой вытащить тег Х из html?».

Comment: @VladD выбор регулярки для парсинга html - это техническая проблема. можно вычленить основную проблем - парсинг - и решить ее. Пусть даже решений будет несколько. А выбор пиво, анекдота или планирование собственного будущего - это не технические проблемы. Их нельзя *решить*. Можно лишь *высказать мнение*. Нельзя поставить "mark as answer" на мнении. Я не говорю, что высказывание мнения - это плохо или бесполезно. Просто это вне формата SO (и должно быть облито бензином и сожжено!!!!)

Comment: @PashaPash: формат определяем мы. Поэтому «должно быть сожжено!!!!» нуждается в обосновании, и на каждый восклицательный знак вдвое более серьёзном. И в консенсусе участников сайта.

Comment: Ваш пример - это рассуждение на тему, а не вопрос. Он изначально поставлен не верно. Основная же идея примера "Что нужно знать начинающему Java-программисту?" заключается в том, что многие знатоки с радостью ответят на простые профессиональные вопросы не менее качественно, чем на сложные, а результирующие знания будут, как минимум не хуже чем в случае со сложными вопросами. Все зависит от сообщества и правил в нем. В описании метки указывается не более научная информация, чем в приведенном мной примере, вся разница лишь в восприятии и дейсвтиях (как мы подходим к написанию описания) сообщества

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Информация, которая не вписывается в формат QA, не просто так на всех сайтах SE убирается из QA и в лучшем случае переносится в описание метки. Статья, которая пишется и верифицируется коллективно (порог для редактирвоания статьи метки без подтверждения вне беты заоблачный — 20К, значит, любое исправление проверяется) — в этом формате уже можно отвечать на открытые вопросы, да. Но это уже совсем не QA, и приделано сбоку. Разрешать отвечать (1+) и комментировать (50+) всем подряд без проверок (для вики 200+) — это напрашиваться на флуд в стиле традиционных форумов. Итог—шум.

Comment: @VladD формат QA задан администрацией. Тематика вопросов - тоже.

Comment: @PashaPash: Вы про формально или фактически?

Comment: @VladD формально. Практически тематика задается как  вопрошающими так и просматривающими очереди на удаление (многие из которых вообще не высказываются на мете).

Comment: @PashaPash Я безусловно согласен с вами, что шума не должно быть, но уровень шума зависит от сообщества, и в первую очередь, от пользователей с большой репутацией. Именно они  могут удалить ненужный комментарий или отклонить не верную правку. Я лишь хочу подчеркнуть, что очень многие вопросы, которые, на первый взгляд, выглядят плохими, могут получить превосходный ответ и быть востребованными.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky -  "любимый анекдот" - надо закрывать по вашим критериям или нет? А вопрос "что мне делать по жизни" - надо или нет?

Comment: @PashaPash [Ответ на первое](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), ко второму отношение примерно такое же.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "Любимый анекдот" не соответствует пункту №3: *"Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?"*. Один из трёх — это не два из трёх.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Имею в виду, что вопрос про любимый анекдот наберёт плюсов, и на этом его достоинства кончаются. Два остальных критерия Джеффа (онтопик и полезность) не соблюдаются.

Comment: Идея в том, если я не ошибаюсь, что если вопрос не соответствует хотя бы одному из критериев, вопросу не место на сайте.

Answer (score 3):

Акцент на улучшении сигнал/шум отношения при поиске решений технических задач в ущерб общения и дискуссий **заложен в самом движке SO**: сортировка ответов по голосам, ограничение вложенности веток двумя уровнями (ответы, комментарии), сворачивание и вторичная роль комментариев, "золотой молот"  для вопросов-дубликатов итд.

Другие вещи (такие как: слишком *простых вопросов не бывает* (бывают бесполезные, без хороших ответов), ориентируясь на *"квалифицированного в другой области"* человека, или что на вопросы кажущимися "всеобъемлющими" можно содержательно ответить, используя зум: более специфичные вопросы получают более детальные ответы, *опираясь на факты и опыт в разработке*) **на уровне культуры сообщества поддерживаются**, то есть необходимо хотя бы примерное согласие среди участников, которые активны в [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review).

Не ясно как можно усилить предпочтение ошибаться в либеральную сторону **на период первоначального роста сайта**, то есть оставлять открытыми вопросы, которые возможно стоило бы и закрыть, чтобы уменьшить вероятность закрытия "невинных" вопросов (аналогия с почтой: лучше пропустить письмо со спамом, чем отсеять "хорошее" письмо).

Я вижу "большевистский" сценарий  работы в случае обнаружения разногласий:  открытие обсуждения на Мете, голосование за разные точки зрения, с последующим документированием консенсуса в официальной справке, если необходимо (или достаточно tl;dr написать для принятого ответа). Общение модераторов с пользователями, которые *явно и намеренно* нарушают достигнутое согласие (модераторы должны выступать только в роли обработчиков исключений (*исключений* -- ключевое слово)).

Comment: SO.RU вообще-то ни разу не в состоянии "первоначального роста". Первоначальный рост был, когда он был Хэшкодом. А сейчас он на 10-м месте по общему количеству вопросов и по количеству вопросов в день среди всех сайтов Stack Exchange, которых почти 150! Звание "бета" у сайта весьма условное.

Comment: @Athari: [по кол-ву вопросов в день SO на русском в десятке находится](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), но по сравнению с большим SO -- сайт всё ещё является лилипутом (100x).

Comment: По сравнению с СО почти все сайты в сети SE лилипуты, однако это не мешает многим из них считаться зрелыми сайтами.

Comment: @Athari: не нужно правила с большого SO перетягивать, не учитывая разницу в масштабе. Может быть SO на русском никогда не вырастет до таких масштабов, чтобы фактически проявились различные проблемы с тематикой задаваемых вопросов. Методы управления дюжиной человек отличаются от методов управления толпой из тысячи.

Comment: Я "перетягиваю" правила не с большого СО, а со всей сети SE. Они действуют на всех сайтах. И если говорить про ранние стадии развития сайтов, то ранее творчество на стадии закрытой беты как раз выпиливают будь здоров — чтобы все вопросы и ответы были вылизанными, соответствовали правилам и подавали хороший пример.

Answer (score 3):

Основная мысль - менталитет у нас другой. Не думаю, что ресурс сможет развивать ту же динамику, работая по тем же правилам, что и на официальном SO.

Предлагаю простое инженерное решение в двух действиях:

1. Анализ активности участников
2. Выработка консолидированных сценариев,
   по которым следует вести те или иные отношения среди участников

Анализ включает разбор полетов по поводу того, как ведут себя участники с <del>гранатой в руке</del> новыми инструментами и легализация этого поведения в некоторых рамках. Рамки нужны для того, чтобы контент ресурса был полезен "читателям" (как раз для того, чтобы не было мусора).

Запретить общение конечно можно, но ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет.

Движок достаточно демократичный, чтобы подстраиваться под любую публику. Не так давно я уже предлагал [один из таких сценариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/76/8766) ведения дискуссий. Наверняка, можно придумать другие. Искать и обсуждать оптимальные варианты.