# А что если разрешить спрашивать мнение об инструментах, библиотеках, книгах и т.п?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, правила, учебные-материалы

По существующим правилам

> Вопросы с просьбами предоставить рекомендации или найти книги,
>   инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие
>   внешние ресурсы

задавать запрещено.

Как думаете, а если отменить это правило,
т.е. **разрешить** спрашивать мнение об инструментах, библиотеках, книгах и т.п., а также просить порекомендовать что-то из этих "запрещенных предметов"
(конечно, применительно к конкретной и ясно описанной в вопросе ситуации (а это уже относится к *качеству вопроса*)),
то сайт станет действительно хуже?

И заодно, может не стоит требовать от вопроса **однозначного ответа**?

(мое мнение — сайт только улучшится; не нужно — на многие хорошие вопросы все же однозначно ответить нельзя)

Comment: Я за ослабление ограничений.

Comment: Я тоже за это изменение.

Comment: Ну мое мнение известно - я только за.

Comment: Это ведь всё приводит к бесконечным дискуссиями "какой инструмент лучше?", спаму "попробуйте мою библиотеку", увеличение лени со стороны авторов вопросов ("зачем разбираться и что-то искать - можно просто спросить"). Как долго ответы на такие вопросы будут актуальными - неизвестно.

Comment: Как было озвучено в принятом ответе на [этот вопрос](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923), _don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy_. Это, конечно, тоже несколько размытый вопрос, но всё же лучше изначального.

Comment: @Regent, не нравятся такие дискуссии -- не читайте. По поводу же последнего -- впечатление, что эти люди просто боятся отвечать за *свои конкретные* советы и поэтому предпочитают заняться  "преподавательством".

Comment: @avp Было бы здорово увидеть ваши мысли в ответе на этот вопрос! Без этого сообщество не сможет за него проголосовать. Как мне кажется, сейчас среди ответов нет того, который бы полностью соответствовал вашей точки зрения.

Answer (score 17):

Полностью согласен с [ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/629/6) [@ReinRaus](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/481/reinraus). Всю общую информацию по какой-либо технологии лучше включать в описание соответствующей метки. Если информации становится чересчур много, можно вынести её в отдельный общий вопрос (например, так поступили с [литературой по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/)).

Почему не стоит допускать подобные вопросы в "стандартной" форме? Причин очень много. Постараюсь задеть главные, на мой взгляд.

- По опыту известно, что подобные вопросы привлекают слишком много внимания неквалифицированных специалистов, ведь каждый хочет показать, что он принадлежит к той или иной группе, любит определенные технологии и т. д. Зачастую такие вопросы не объективны и не содержательны. Как результат, информация представленная на страницах сайта теряет ценность. К сожалению, ценность теряет и весь проект.
- Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество знатоков. Чтобы отобразить на сколько большой вклад в развитие проекта внес тот или иной участник, используется система репутации. Репутация также показывает, на сколько сообщество доверяет конкретному участнику. Разместив душевный ответ, который понравится сотням пользователей, автор получит дополнительные привилегии для управления сообществом далеко не за знания или профессионализм, чего быть не должно.
- Вопросы, подразумевающие ответы основанные на мнениях порождают слишком жаркие дискуссии, которым не место на профессиональном ресурсе. Для этого есть специальные проекты, вконтакте, например.
- Stack Overflow на русском - это профессиональный инструмент, аналогичный, например, средам разработки, системам контроля версий или компиляторам. Все эти инструменты, включая Stack Overflow на русском, позволяют повысить эффективность нашего труда и качество результирующего продукта. Как мне кажется, если бы среда разработки была оформлена в ярких розовых цветах, пестрила бы анимированными баннерами со всех сторон, то использовать её было бы крайне неудобно. Так и Stack Overflow на русском будет не возможно использовать в повседневной трудовой деятельности если в сообществе будет большое количество шума создаваемого дискуссионными вопросами.
- Stack Overflow на русском позволяет воссоздать окружение корпорации в контексте знаний. То есть не важно, в компании какого размера мы работаем, мы все равно можем получить квалифицированную помощь коллег совершенно бесплатно. Давайте представим, что мы работаем в большой компании. У нас возник вопрос, который мы хотим задать коллеге. Если вопрос интересный и полезны, коллега с радостью поможет нам. Если же мы подойдем к нему/ней с вопросом на вроде "где скачать библиотеку", уверен, ответ если и будет, то очень грубый. В первом случае - это профессиональное общение, во втором мы просто отвлекаем человека от работы. Проецируя ситуацию на Интернет-сообщество мы видим тоже самое: дискуссионные вопросы только отвлекают своим шумом знатоков от реальных задач.

Разрешая вопросы-опросники и/или вопросы, подразумевающие дискуссионные ответы или ответы основанные на мнение мы фактически превращаем сообщество из профессионального ресурса коллективной помощи в чат по интересам.

Мы рискуем кардинально изменить окружение в худшую сторону. Сегодня заходя на Stack Overflow на русском пользователь видит хорошие прикладные вопросы. Человек подсознательно понимает, что вопросы вида "Как стать программистом-философом за 2,3 дня?" не будут приняты сообществом (он сам не будет принят). Уверен, разрешив такие вопросы, в скором будущем, в сообщество "подтянутся" аналогичные пользователи, как результат, сайт превратится в свалку информации сомнительного качества.

---

Все же, лично я считаю, что решение об закрытие/удаление очень сильно зависит от оформления вопроса. Я постарался раскрыть идею в публикации "[Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271/)". Если вы видите вопрос, на который вы хотели бы ответить сами или хотели бы увидеть ответ другого знатока, но который не отвечает требованиям ресурса, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку, чтобы он соответствовал стандартам и правилам Stack Overflow на русском.

Comment: Присоединяюсь и позволю себе заметить, что тема [уже обсуждалась](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/162/10105).

Answer (score 10):

Мне кажется, что ответы на такие вопросы должны быть в вики соответствующих меток.
У каждого есть инструменты для внесения информации в вики.

Вот пример вики, который я стараюсь развивать по мере своего времени:
[регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). Туда я внес полезные книги, которые сам читал и оценил. Предлагаю всем желающим делать похожие вики по другим меткам.

Comment: по книгам было решено собирать коммьюнити-посты и ссылаться на них из вики

Comment: @Nofate а мне нравится как сделано на англостеке: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info . Вики самодостаточна и не нуждается в связанных коммьюнити-постах.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584 - довольно большой объем.

Comment: @Nofate наверно надо смотреть по объему. В регулярках например достойной литературы единицы и нет смысла выносить в отдельный пост, а вот для популярных языков, возможно, будет лучше пост. Хотя я вроде видел, что в маркдауне можно спойлер делать. Может лучше спойлерами большие объемы книг вносить? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers

Comment: Отличная штука - раздел "Как задать вопрос про регулярные выражения". Да и вообще описание очень качественно написано.

Comment: @ReinRaus: это не развертывающийся спойлер. Это как цитата, только текст не видно, пока курсор не наведешь. Применяется во всяких Puzzling.

Comment: Хотел добавить свои 5 копеек про то, что такие вопросы часто привлекают чисто-ссылочные ответы, которые не являются самодостаточными. А тут уже и решение есть.

Answer (score 8):

Вот если бы принудительно ответы на такие вопросы делать в формате "один ответ - один совет/книга/ссылка/и т.п.".. А то запостит кто-то простыню из 40 книг и попробуй разберись и проголосуй какая из них лучше подходит к вопросу..

При этом по прежнему жестко модерировать вопросы:

- разжигающий холивары (какой язык выучить, на чем написать прогу и т.п.)
- слишком широкие (что прочесть в поезде, где найти бест-практики)

То есть в идеале наверно должны быть вопросы с четким указанием области, по которой нужны рекомендации и четким описанием желаемой цели.

Например:

- Посоветуйте книгу по OpenGL 4.0+ для начинающего
- Посоветуйте уроки по работе с микроконтроллерами ST832ххх в С++

Comment: *Посоветуйте уроки по работе с микроконтроллерами ST832ххх в С++*, обязательно **видеоуроки** )

Comment: Можно и видео, почему нет ))

Comment: У нас вроде получился неплохой [список книг по C#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105) с описаниями и рубрикацией.

Answer (score 8):

Я лично считаю, что лучше не разрешать просьбы о рекомендации и вопросы без однозначного ответа. По моему опыту [на английском Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546661/peter-olson), такие вопросы в болшинстве не являются полезными.

Тем не менее, я за ослабление ограничений. Почему? Я думаю, что для нас очень важно попробовать и узнать, что получится. Если разрешим, и получится, что качество нашего сообщества понижается, тогда можно обсудить и передумать. А если попробуем, и получится хорошо, то оставим эту возможность.

Comment: Да, я за контролируемый эксперимент. По крайней мере за то, чтобы попробовать расширить круг допустимых вопросов тематикой Programmers.

Comment: Ок, хорошо. Комментарии удаляю.

Comment: Насколько я помню, Programmers.SE изначально отпочковался от SO и чуть было не стал "кладбищем плохих для SO вопросов". Ru.SO ещё не настолько вырос, чтобы отделение было необходимо, так что попробовать стоит.

Answer (score 4):

Почему бы не уводить авторов таких вопросов в чат, где каждый может поделиться с ними своим мнением, не нарушая правил и не замусоривая SO информацией, которую не сложно найти с помощью поисковой системы.

Comment: Потому что это не замусоривание, а полезная информация. Гораздо более полезная, чем очередной поиск минимального элемента в массиве.

Comment: Часто, когда вижу вопрос типа «что мне учить: жиквери или ангуляр», создаю под ним чат, чтобы желающие могли поделиться мнением.

Answer (score 3):

Исходя из опыта использования англоязычной версии stackoverflow, полагаю, что сложившаяся система правил как раз таки делает поиск решения на этом сайте возникшей проблемы предельно эффективной, поскольку часто ответ на интересующий вопрос четко сформулирован, и нет необходимости его искать среди тонны комментариев и флуда. Эффективность решений, принятой администрацией stackoverflow, подтверждает заслуженная популярность этого сервиса.

Comment: Ваш ответ исходит из предположения, что community на en.SO и ru.SO можно управлять одинаковым образом. Это по факту не так, и обсуждению этого посвящено много постов здесь, на Мете.

Answer (score 3):

Все проще. Если тред по старой традиции начинает скатываться в обсуждение криворукости авторов какой-то библиотеки, тупости вопрошающего, взаимные перепалки, обмен субъективными мнениями или посоветуй, достаточно просто запретить его внешнюю индексацию  поисковой системой через robots.txt, отключить внутреннюю индексацию и сделать невидимым в выдаче без прямой ссылки.

Такую возможность нужно добавить либо в модпанель либо пустить ее через голосование.

В итоге все довольны. Тред как бы есть для заинтересованных участников, но в то же время для остального мира его вроде как и нет.

P.S. Ничего не имею против таких тем и даже за, это весело.

Comment: На мой взгляд, жизненно важной характеристикой сообщества является окружение. Если профессионал попадает на свалку информации, не думаю, что он/она захочет публиковать свой хороший вопрос там же. Stack Overflow - это инструмент. Он создан для того чтобы решить определенные задачи. То есть даже если поисковик не увидит это содержимое, то пользователи точно увидят. Есть большая вероятность, что это сделает "инструмент" неэффективным.

Comment: @Nicolas Судя по моему опыту вообще весь HTTP траффик в мире вне зависимости от конкретного хоста это одна большая гигантская никем не контроллируемая свалка информации. Однако это никого не смущают и новые и новые посты все продолжаются и продолжатся, снова и снова.

Comment: Мне кажется, отчасти и по этому, модель Stack Overflow так популярна среди разработчиков, и вообще, среди ИТ-специалистов. Stack Overflow позволяет: 1) каталогизировать информацию и 2) оптимизировать её для чтения. Все это приводит к кристаллизации знаний, что делает Интернет чуть-чуть более полезным :)

Comment: @Nicolas Надеюсь что сообщество сможет коллективными усилиями хотя бы немного поспособствовать этому.

Comment: Historical lock именно так и работает.

Answer (score 2):

@NicolasChabanovsky, Вы правы, сейчас среди ответов нет того, который бы полностью соответствовал моей точке зрения.

Дело тут в том, что мне более интересен процесс обсуждения (совершенно не обязательно с моим участием) и поиска правильного решения, общение в обсуждении
(конечно, профессиональных тем (желательно бы на уровне, который не гуглится (правда, с этим всегда были проблемы)), хотя и "как нам обустроить Россию", и эвтаназия Доктора в прямом эфире на флудильне были любопытны),
чем конечный результат (накопление конкретных рекомендаций в формате однозначных Q&A), на что и заточены существующие правила и движок.

Кстати, я поразмыслил и пришел к выводу, что три вещи, которые исчезли:

- тема при комментировании не поднимается в топ на главной странице;
- невозможность форматирования кода в комментариях;
- отсутствие нотификации всех участников темы (ну, в полной мере ее и не было);

практически убирают дух прежнего ХК (по крайней мере теперь ожидать чего-либо действительно интересного просто наивно).

Я не хочу делать какие-либо прогнозы насчет перспектив нынешнего формата. Сразу скажу, что в конечном итоге желаю всем успехов и радужного (в традиционном смысле этого выражения:)) будущего.

Сам же, пока просто понаблюдаю и почитаю, например [это](http://elementy.ru/) (пока вслед за фондом Зимина не закрылось).

Answer (score 2):

Если уж на то пошло, можно просто две категории сделать - прикладные вопросы и дискуссионно-теоретические (или как-то подругому их назвать). И две галочки справа, отвечающие за показ той или иной категории.

А можно без изменений движка - просто сделать для таких вопросов **отдельную метку**

Comment: Для дискуссий есть чаты. Изначальная идея в том, что любой вопрос на Stack Overflow (и ответы к нему)  может быть многократно использован людьми, попадающими на сайт из поисковика. Дискуссии имеют много недостатков, базовые два: 1) крайне сложно найти, как именно была решена проблема (да и то, в чем она заключалось), 2) дискуссии зачастую уникальны. Все это делает их полезными исключительно для участвующих людей, а это единицы в сравнение с тысячами приходящими из поисковика.

Comment: Чаты в этом случае решают проблему. Таким образом, обсудив проблему в чате, можно вернуться на сайт, детально описать проблему и опубликовать финальное решение.