# Просьбы посоветовать книгу и т. п

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, тематика, учебные-материалы

Было уже [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/623/%D0%90-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) и не раз.

Ладно, если ответ вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/15479). Но по большей части ответы на вопросы с просьбой поделиться книгами/туториалами/тестами ограничиваются списком ссылок. А как мы знаем ответы-ссылки не приветствуются. Взять например [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/46061/15479) ответ. Вроде неплох, но чуть менее чем полностью состоит из ссылок.

Да и сами по себе подобные вопросы не подразумевают однозначного ответа. Многие подобные вопросы просто закрываются. Но не все. [Этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33571/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript), к примеру, нет. И ответы там в виде голых ссылок.

Так всё же, как относится к подобным вопросам и что делать с ответами-ссылками?

Comment: так уже писали про это - если есть канонический вопрос - закрываем как дубликат, можно перенести хорошие книжки в тот вопрос, если такого вопроса нет и можно текущий сделать хорошим - делаем его. Голые ссылки на книги можно сделать относительно хорошими - в ответе пишем название книги, авторов и ссылку на какой-нибудь магазин. Даже если ссылка в магазине протухнет - по названию книги и автору все равно можно будет найти эту книгу. Т.е. ссылка здесь будет просто как дописточник, главное чтобы по названию книги можно было ее найти (можно, например, и isbn привести)

Comment: [вот здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/162/5079) же нормальное предложение. А [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/5079) собираем эти самые канонические вопросы, тогда закрывать проще будет

Comment: @BOPOH а если ссылка уже не доступна, и не понять, на какую книгу ссылалась?

Comment: ну тогда это ответ типа: *я в школе читал книгу, как зовут не помню, но что-то там по теме было*, т.е. удалять и не жалеть, все равно от такой "книги" толку никакого

Comment: а вот формат описания книг проработать можно, например, как в списке литературы по госту указывать, но стоит ли оно того?

Comment: @BOPOH если есть возможность, то, думаю, стоит по гост'у. Хотя, название+автор+год вполне достаточно, по-моему.

Comment: @BOPOH: я недавно видел рекомендацию «книга с носорогом».

Comment: @NickVolynkin, насколько помню, это образно было сказано, типа книги этой серии читать надо, а не отсылка к какому-то конкретному экземпляру

Comment: @BOPOH: там в этой серии десятки книг, насколько я помню, все с разными животными. Вот этот ответ: [javascript - учебник](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/99228)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, похоже был не прав, гугл знает о книге с носорогом ) я че-то думал что носорога на нескольких книгах видел

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR: закрывать как дубли канонических списков литературы; если списка нет, то «зависит от мнений»**

Ответ про литературу по C#, на который вы ссылаетесь — из соответствующего вопроса, созданного специально как список литературы. Эти вопрос и ответ имеют право на жизнь, потому что сообщество решило хранить списки литературы в такой форме, и потому что они соответствуют строгим требованиям:

- Вопрос с шаблонной формулировкой
- Вопрос является общим
- Единственный ответ в виде списка
- Ответ является общим
- Список выполнен в едином формате, не содержит ссылок на нелегальные источники и битых ссылок

Все канонические списки литературы перечислены здесь (если какого-то нет в списке, то добавляйте):

[Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/181472)

Все остальные вопросы в идеале необходимо отмечать дублями к таким каноническим вопросам. Если соответствующего списка нет, то нужно создать новый вопрос-список и отмечать к нему. Пока списка нет, просто закрывайте как too broad или зависит от мнений.

Важно, что нужно именно создавать новый вопрос, переделывать имеющийся нельзя:

- Нужно будет уговаривать автора принять ответ
- Нужно будет отметить вопрос общим, что сложно сделать против воли автора
- Вероятно, нужно будет перекроить текст вопроса

Comment: "*закрывать как дубли канонических списков литературы*" — А что делать, если списка нет?

Comment: @Discord: если возможно, идти и создавать список. Если нет — просто закрывать, а потом перезакрывать как дубль с помощью модератора.

Comment: Так с какой причиной закрывать-то?

Comment: @Discord: с последней в списке на первой странице.

Comment: важный момент, отсутствующий в этом списке, [как я уже говорил](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c/162#comment301_162) -- это сортировка. Новые вопросы могут сперва (пока сортировка не устаканится) содержать много ответов (один ответ -- одна книга) -- голосование определяет порядок книг в принятом ответе.

Comment: @jfs: интересная идея. Но так книги отсортируются по популярности, а не по качеству. Я бы доверил сортировку команде экспертов, которые прочитали весь список — но где таких найти на каждый вопрос.

Comment: голосование работает абсолютно также как и для всех других вопросов на SO -- не всегда более популярные ответы лучше, но *как правило* это так.

Answer (score 2):

Подобные вопросы следует закрывать. Вообще-то у нас была отдельная причина "рекомендация стороннего ресурса, литературы, библиотеки и т. п.", но её переименовали в "опросник", а недавно удалили, при этом не вернув оригинал. Поэтому её нет. Но эти вопросы онтопиком никто не объявлял, правила с тех пор не менялись.

В целом, все вопросы с рекомендацией сторонних ресурсов запрещены. С некоторой толерантностью можно отнестись к рекомендациям библиотек, если описана конкретная проблема, попытки решения и прочая информация, то есть вопрос сводится к решению проблемы, а не к поиску "лучшей библиотеки".

Как закрывать? Ну, вопрос интересный. Я бы закрывал как "too broad" за неимением лучшего варианта. В наших реалиях эта причина называется "необходимо конкретизировать вопрос". Хотя в случае литературы это и звучит несколько (совсем) бредово.

Comment: "рекомендация стороннего ресурса..." - "посоветуйте ссылку на so, где описаны такие-то и такие-то библиотеки", и ответ: "вот, ссылка на (и ссылка на этот самый вопрос), где описаны эти библиотеки, например: (и идет перечисление ссылок на библиотеки)". Так можно? )))

Comment: @BOPOH У вас слишком абстрактный пример. Я не понимаю, что такое "описание библиотеки на СО".

Comment: а если правилами запрещено, но большинство следует "своим" правилам - можно ли говорить о том, что правила разрешают? На ответе @Vlad все-таки голосов больше ) А пример - тупая попытка вопрос не по правилам (нельзя просить ссылки на внешние ресурсы) сделать вопросом по правилам (просим ссылку НЕ на внешний ресурс)

Comment: @BOPOH Если вы про общие вопросы и ответы по литературе, то они исключены из системы правил. Я считаю это бредом (на большом СО для этого используется вики меток), но народу нравится. / А ваш вопрос принципиально не отличается от "найдите мне ответ на СО, мне самому лень". Это покрывается причиной для закрытия "дубликат".

Answer (score 2):

Поправил описания меток [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) и [литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0). Теперь они явно призывают к тому, чтобы не задавать новых вопросов, а идти в общий список, а оттуда - в соответствующий канонический вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Если есть подходящий канонический ответ, то закрывать как дубликат.

Если нет, то оставлять. Хоть какой-то контент наберётся, а потом можно будет и эталонный ответ собрать. А этот закрыть. Что касается ссылок, то для книг названия достаточно, чтобы найти, поэтому ссылка является просто дополнительной информацией и не может рассматриваться как причина для закрытия/удаления.

Comment: Речь об ответах-ссылках, где нет названия даже. Я таких уже не мало встречал. Особенно в старых вопросах.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а если дописать название?

Comment: Если ссылка мёртвая, то никак...