# В чём причина закрытия вопроса о перечислении примеров/продуктов?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Я задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183223/lisp-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment2059640_1183223) о продуктах. Но сообщество на него прореагировало негативно. Этот вопрос сочли необъективным. Почему - не ясно. Он вполне конкретный и на него можно дать вполне конкретный ответ с примерами и ссылками. В чём причина закрытия?

Comment: Вопросы типа "Дайте список АВС" плохо подходят для формата SO. На них, обычно, есть статьи в Википедии или на других, специализированных, ресурсах

Comment: Есть причина закрытия "Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ". Смысл в том, что нельзя оценить, правильный ответ или нет, -- один даст ссылку на один проект, второй -- на другой. Но если вы сами дадите каноничный вопрос-ответ, как сборники литературы по языкам, то думаю, никто не будет закрывать, а будут в будущем делать дубликаты на этот вопрос

Comment: @dlm0n так где же на мнениях, когда на фактах. Либо используется лисп, либо нет. Возможно с раскрытием подробностей: какую роль исполняет. Другое дело, что я не знал о том, что такие вопрос не подходят для формата SO. Хотя это и странно. Я об этом не слышал и в правилах не видел

Comment: @Kromster это очень странно, поскольку на so есть вагон и маленькая тележка вопросов по темам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-python

Comment: Аналогичного или даже близкого вопроса про lisp нет

Comment: "Книги и учебные ресурсы" были специально обсуждены на Мете и для них сделано исключение (хотя и не однозначное). https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/623

Comment: вопрос вполне разумный и подходящий для базы знаний, зря его закрыли. я бы предложил тегировать вопрос тегом [tag:поиск-программ], возможно это сможет смягчить проверяющих

Comment: @nörbörnën есть разница между поиском программы для решения конкретной задачи (для этого предназначена метка [tag:поиск-программ], см. [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2615)) и вопросом "Какие продукты/решения существуют на lisp?". В первом случае в идеале получится короткий список из 2-3 программ (ну 5 максимум), в во втором случае получится список из 10-100 программ (и каждый приходящий будет накидывать еще 10 программ), никак не связанных между собой кроме языка программирования, на котором они написаны.

Comment: @insolor вопрос в том, что программы на lisp не то что распространены. Именно поэтому я и задал этот вопрос.

Comment: @hedgehogues все равно это слишком общий вопрос. Фактически любой завтра может написать на lisp свой самый крутой hello world или какой-нибудь ничего не делающий сервис, назвать его "продуктом"/"решением" и этот "продукт" формально будет подходить под ваш вопрос. Если сравнивать со списками книг/учебных ресурсов или вопросами по поиску программ (решающих конкретную задачу) - не каждый может написать книгу, или создать достойный внимания учебный ресурс, либо например создать полноценный редактор какого-то формата файла или IDE.

Comment: @insolor я [задалъ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183550/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85). уверен, что нет однозначного ответа на мой вопрос, закроешь? :)

Comment: @nörbörnën, есть описание конкретной проблемы, которую нужно решить - вполне нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @hedgehogues, они не правы.

Comment: @avp неправы относительно того, что такие вопросы следует закрывать?

Comment: @hedgehogues, именно так (и многие другие вопросы тоже)

Comment: @avp например ещё?

Comment: @hedgehogues, я не коллекционирую ссылки