# Какие вопросы не по теме (администрирование и маркетинг)?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика, причины-закрытия

На хэшкоде было принято считать не по по теме вопросы про администрирование. Вопросы про маркетинг никогда не закрывали.

Сейчас судя по всему наоборот ([открытые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436915/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436303/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-yaml-%D0%B2-php-fpm) [про](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436204/phpdaemon-%D0%BD%D0%B0-amazon-ec2) [администрирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436875/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ip-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Вопросы про маркетинг пока закрыть не успели, но народ голосует за закрытие)

Comment: Все тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

#### Почему про администрирование — подходит

Области специализации специалистов в программировании и администрировании очень близки. Те и другие часто разбираются в shell, bash, контроле версий, sql...

#### Почему про маркетинг — не подходит

Совершенно разные специализации и области деятельности. Есть достаточно мало людей, которые на рабочем месте занимаются одновременно разработкой ПО и маркетингом/монетизацией/продажами. Исключение — инди-разработчики, которые сами пишут приложение и сами его же и монетизируют. Но это достаточно небольшая ниша, на мой взгляд.

#### Цитирую справку:

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> - к конкретной задаче программирования - коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
> - к инструментам для разработки - языки программирования, среды, операционные системы, пакеты программ, фреймворки, библиотеки;
> - к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;
> - к настройке физических, виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их
>   настройки, мониторинга и этих автоматизации процессов;
> - к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для
>   разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального
>   администрирования IT систем.

Comment: @Nofate спасибо, не заметил.

Comment: *мониторинга и **этих** автоматизации* — я уже [исправлял](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/154/revisions). а в справке до сих пор старый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я нашёл ответ (цитата [отсюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85)):

*Учитывая сказанное выше, давайте рассмотрим, какие вопросы являются тематическими для сообщества. В самой общей формулировке можно сказать, что:
Любой прикладной вопрос по программированию или системному администрированию, на который можно дать однозначно верный ответ, а также вопросы по программированию или системному администрированию, читая которые можно быстро обучиться чему-то новому, будут тематическими для сообщества.*