# Администрирование серверов по теме или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Все таки вопросы про администрирование серверов разрешены или нет? Есть две правки меток

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/206714
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/206799

Одна из которых отправляет на ServerFault, а другая предлагает такие вопросы тут задавать. Обе приняты. Почему?

Comment: Обе правки некорректны

Comment: Онтопик. См. также следующие топики на мете: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/225/213987), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/845/213987), [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1291/213987).

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда и в конце подробного описания тоже поправить надо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/smtp/info

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Да, по теме.

А вот отправлять в англоязычные сообщества где-то было признано неправильным.

Answer (score 3):

[help/on-topic говорит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>   ...
>
> - настройке физических и виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их настройки, мониторинга и автоматизации процессов;

то есть вопросы по администрированию серверов явно по теме и уже [не первый год](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/225/23044).

Вопросы на русском языке являются off-topic на английских ресурсах. Даже на английском, наличие других сайтов, на которых можно подобные вопросы задать не делает их off-topic на этом сайте. [Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/4279)