# Всегда ли нужно закрывать вопрос, где проблема связана с опечаткой?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Только что наблюдал вопрос, закрытый с формулировкой "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой."

[Не работает сравнение строк из EditText с образцами строк по нажатию кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443169/181472)

При этом если внимательно прочитать вопрос и ответы, то оказывается, что ошибок в коде несколько.

1. Опечатка в названиях переменных, которая и спровоцировала закрытие.<sup>1</sup>
2. Значения сравниваемых переменных присваиваются в момент инициализации, а не в момент сравнения, что нарушает логику. Даже после исправления опечатки эта ошибка остается.
3. (На мой субъективный взгляд) копипаста в коде, которая нарушает DRY, спровоцировала опечатку и спровоцирует многочисленные ошибки в будущем, если ее не искоренять.

Мне кажется, что проверяющие увидели в комментариях слово "опечатка" и не стали разбираться с остальным, решив, что всё и так ясно.

(1)  Заметьте, что [третьей правкой автор сам исправил эту опечатку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/443169/revisions). Плохо, что вместе с ней он исправил и остальные ошибки (эти изменения я потом откатил обратно)

Как вы считаете, достаточно ли того, что в коде есть опечатка, чтобы закрыть с такой формулировкой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Цитирую [инструкцию по закрыванию ошибок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271/181472):

> Закрывая тему, мы говорим автору, что его вопрос не соответствует
> стандартам форума, что нет никого, кто бы мог исправить содержание
> сообщения, и более того, никто не собирается публиковать ответы. На
> наш взгляд, так стоит поступать с теми вопросами, которые нарушают
> идеологию проекта:
>
> - слишком локальные вопросы (например, вызванные опечаткой);
> - вопросы вида “найди ошибку в моем коде” с условием, что они никак и никому, за исключением автора, не смогут помочь в будущем;

**О данном конкретном вопросе**

В этом вопросе несколько ошибок. Одна из них - тривиальная опечатка. Но другая - ошибка в построении логики приложения. Автор вопроса сравнивает значение из текстового поля с константой, причем значение из поля получает невовремя. Часто ли реализуется такая логика? Часто - в любой валидации форм, в диалогах авторизации, даже в том диалоге, в котором я сейчас пишу ответ.

**О вопросах с опечатками в целом**

Эта схема иллюстрирует тот способ, который я считаю правильным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что это – главный пункт данной причины закрытия:

> решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям

То есть, закрываем вопросы с опечаткой в коде, потому что есть очень маленькая вероятность, что у других будет та же проблема. Если проблема не только одна опечатка, а несколько, или там есть еще некоторые проблемы, то вероятность даже меньше.

Поэтому, мне кажется, что если следует закрывать вопросы с одной опечаткой, тем паче следует закрывать вопросы с еще несколькими проблемами.

Comment: Но ведь можно же, исправив опечатку, изменить вопрос так, что бы акцент был направлен на реальные проблемы. Тогда можно считать что опечатки, как бы, и не было.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я бы даже в коде вопроса исправлял опечатку сразу, если есть проблемы кроме нее. Но не уверен, что это хорошо. Поэтому и поднял обсуждение.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если автор после указания на опечатку подтверждает, что проблема осталась, то нужно редактировать вопрос (в идеале, это должен делать сам автор).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а он, кстати, отредактировал.