# Следует ли помечать тревогой закрытые вопросы-опросники для их удаления модератором или жать "Удалить"?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, удаление-вопросов

**Дано:**

Вопросы опросники, закрытые, с положительной суммой голосов и ответами с голосами. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1394 (закрыто)

**Вопрос:**

Что же с ними делать?

1. Ничего? Они сами как-то исчезнут/не мешают?
2. Жать на `удалить`? Так, вроде, оно попадёт в очередь и будет удалено роботом?
3. Жать на тревогу, призывать модератора и расти в прогрессе получения значка за полезные тревоги?

Ссылка в тему: [Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях? (ответ Discord)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274/)

Comment: Если уж очень хочется поудалять старый оффтопик - пройдитесь по http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, что у нас предлагается по кнопке "тревога":

- спам
  Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.  ***(хм, слетел перевод!)***
- невежливый или оскорбительный
  A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.
- требуется вмешательство модератора
  Другая проблема, требующая реакции модератора. Опишите её подробно и конкретно!

Первые две причины обычно не подходят для закрытых вопросов, так как такие вопросы обычно удаляются крайне быстро.

Третья причина нужна только в случае, если случилось что-то нетривиальное, что действительно обязательно требует работы модератора. Удаление вопросов не входит в этот список. Поэтому я считаю, что заниматься зарабатыванием значка за полезные тревоги на подобных вопросах не стоит, так как это может сильно отвлекать модератора от более важных задач.

Если вопрос закрыт и действительно находится вне тематики сообщества, то можно нажать на кнопку "удалить". Если вы не одиноки в своём мнении или если вопрос подпадает под условия сборки *Духом сообщества*, то через некоторое время он действительно удалится.

Если вопрос закрыли случайно, стоит нажать на кнопку "переоткрытие", так как иногда такое случается (к указанному вами вопросу это не относится).

Ещё некоторые потенциально хорошие вопросы, которые закрыли, можно попробовать отредактировать и после этого отправить на переоткрытие, на случай например, если у вас есть хороший ответ.

---

Если ответить на изначальный вопрос, то я считаю, что нет, поднимать тревогу не нужно, и если вопрос заслуживает досрочное удаление, нажать кнопку "удалить".