# Снимается ли репутация, полученная за ответ на удалённый вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, репутация, удаление-вопросов

**Гипотетическая ситуация:**

Например, пришёл человек, задал вопрос связанный с опечаткой (например), я от нечего делать (ну не работу же работать) её увидел, написал ответ, получил +15. Потом набегают закрыватели и минусовщики. Вопрос закрывают и робот его удаляет.

**Вопрос:**

Таки исчезнут мои `+15` или нет? Про минусы к карме, полученной за вопрос, в чате говорят, что они исчезают.

Т.е. имеет ли смысл отвечать на вопросы, кои очевидно `закроют->удалят` если оч. хочется многа кармы?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Да, репутация удаляется, и это очень хорошо.**

Незачем отвечать на вопросы, которые очевидно не по теме сайта. Одна из их проблем как раз в том, что они позволяют получать дешевую репутацию.

Представьте, что некто задал вопрос:

> «А правда что jQuery лучше всех?»

Сразу же прибегает эксперт:

> «Да, jQuery ваще ништяк, используйте её для всего»

И второй

> «Нет, jQuery фигня, выкиньте ее на помойку, я использую Drupal».

<sub>(да, я знаю, что это разные вещи. Это сарказм)</sub>

Потом приходят ещё много разных школокодеров, плюсуют вопрос и оба ответа. Если повторить это много раз, то что у нас получится? Получатся участники с высокой репутацией (т.е. с большими возможностями модерации), которые

- не имеют никаких реальных знаний в предметной области (по крайней мере, это не требуется)
- не создают полезного содержимого
- не понимают, как устроен Stack Overflow
- [злоупотребляют возможностями модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1409/181472)

Поэтому полностью бесполезные и субъективные вопросы [действительно нужно удалять](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1405/181472).

Однако, вопрос с опечаткой не всегда является бесполезным. Бывают [очень популярные ошибки/опечатки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453619/181472), основанные на непонимании фундаментальных вещей. О них новичкам будет полезно почитать. Но в ответе на такой вопрос хотелось бы видеть понятное объяснение проблемы, а не только «замени А на Б в строке 42».

Comment: Т.е. если в вопросе опечатка, но ответ хорош, то можно попытаться отстоять вопрос и свои +15 в очереди проверок постоянно переоткрывая вопрос с формулировкой "опечатки часты, а ответ хорош"?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: вопрос можно спасти хорошим ответом, но не переоткрытием. Не зря есть знак [Реверс/Reversal](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) — он как раз для таких ситуаций. А голосовать за переоткрытие вопроса можно только один раз, плюс нужны 4 других голоса, так что в одиночку совсем трешовый вопрос не отстоять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб закрытие вопроса не всегда приводит к его удалению. точное условие удаления - закрыт, не locked, рейтинг <= 0, без принятых или upvoted ответов, без голосов за открытия, закрытие больше 9 дней назад и без правок в последние 9 дней. хороший ответ, с хотя бы одним голосом за, удержит весь вопрос от автоудаления. а ручным удалением тут пользуются очень редко.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб т.е. ваши +15 (accepted answer) вполне удержат вопрос от удаления.

Comment: @PashaPash, угу, понял, спасибо)

Comment: Читал и смеялся:)