# Что нам делать с роборевьюерами?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, очередь-проверок

Обнаружил участника, который, как мне кажется, механически выполняет работу по проверке сообщений в очередях. В нормальной ситуации я бы просто сообщил модератору, но тут я настолько... обескуражен, что считаю нужным вынести это на общее рассмотрение.

Итак, смотрим в историю проверок. Я пролистал все 35 страниц и не нашел *ни одного* «Оставить открытым» и ни одного «Открыть повторно». Только «Закрыть» и «Оставить закрытым».

У участника 851 проверка в очереди «Голоса за закрытие» и  119 в очереди «Голоса за повторное открытие». И ни одного голоса в пользу сообщения. Так вообще бывает?

Comment: На обычном SO есть автогенерированные тестовые проверки, чтобы отсекать таких. А здесь я не видел. Думаю, у модераторов есть кнопка «запретить человеку ревьювить».

Comment: @TagirValeev: хорошо бы и нам уже эти тестовые проверки заполучить.

Comment: Забанить навечно. А проверки вроде бы недоступны, пока сайт в бете

Comment: @PashaPash Имеются ввиду тестовые проверки?

Comment: Я сам грешен - в основном закрываю, но ведь и правда вопросов с плохим качеством очень много, а на переоткрытие попадают, в основном, вопросы с исправленными опечатками или добавленным форматированием при том, что чаще они закрыты из-за проблем с содержательной частью

Comment: @tutankhamun: в основном это ведь не 100%. Единственный вариант — участник пропускает, когда не хочет закрывать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Согласен. >1000 вопросов и ни одного стоящего это должно сильно повезти с пользователями, которые первыми забили тревогу. Жалко в формате сайта нельзя просто взять и спросить человека с банхаммером, почему у него предохранитель на нем не срабатывает

Comment: @tutankhamun: ну это не банхаммер, это пока что так, молоточек. Банхаммер — это если Nofate уйдёт в режим берсерка.

Comment: @NickVolynkin кстати, Владимир вроде бы вибирает разные причины закрытия, так что вполне возможно что он просто пропускает то, насчет чего не уверен. ну или не хочет оставлять вообще никакие вопросы открытыми.

Comment: *выбирает, будь прокляты производители клавиатур ноутбуков.

Comment: @PashaPash а с планшетами так просто беда :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin а я даже за ноутбуком сижу без мышки :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для Stack Overflow на русском ранее не были активированы автоматические проверки, о которых упоминает [@TagirValeev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183331/tagir-valeev). Я отправил запрос на их активацию. В ближайшее время, скорее всего, они начнут работать.

Общая идея автоматических проверок заключается в том, что всем участникам с вероятностью 1/25 будет добавляться вопрос не соответствующий очереди (например, хороший вопрос в очередь проверки вопросов плохого качества). Если участник систематически ошибается, он будет отстранен от проверки. Обычно, в случае понимания правил сообщества и ответственного подхода ни у кого не возникает проблем с прохождением теста.

Вторым инструментом регулирования качества проверок является ручная блокировка доступа к очереди. Если в случае с автоматической проверкой система будет блокировать доступ к лишь к определенной очереди, то в случае ручной блокировки участнику будет недоступен весь инструмент.

Comment: В любом случае, инструмент полезный и сообщество знает, что можно сделать запрос на блокировку модераторам.

Comment: Вопрос, кстати, очень полезный оказался. Спасибо! Почему-то все думали, что проверки активированы на всех Stack Overflow, а оказалось, что только на англоязычном.

Comment: да, скорей бы уже запустили.

Comment: то есть португальцы не заметили?

Comment: Возможно, у них все ответственно относятся, либо безответственно, но тоже все. Если есть единство в подходе, пропустить вполне легко.

Comment: Сила в единстве! :)

Comment: с автоматическим аудитом проверок тоже могут быть проблемы. Можно упомянуть что на Мете такие случае можно обсудить.