# Опечатался? Расстрелять!

Tags: обсуждение

Есть вопросы которые вызваны проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится или опечаткой. Они закрываются с интересной надписью: объявлен **требующим правки**.

К примеру [canvas-не-изображает-круги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582280/canvas-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8) . Закрыли. Теперь он висит как дохлик.

Если вопрос вызван опечаткой или больше не воспроизводится, то зачем правка? Что она даст? Ни автору вопроса, ни другим будущим посетителям не поможет сий вопрос и ответ (если он был дан).
Т.к. цель ресурса - база знаний для всех, а этот вопрос такой цели никак не отвечает, то, может, его удалять, а не закрывать с требованием правки?

Т.е., к примеру, если автор вопроса был уведомлен об опечатке (через комментарий или ответ) и сам автор дал понять, что получил уведомление и да - он ошибся (также отписал в комментарии или принял ответ, уведомляющий об этом), то может все таки удалять?
Если удалять, то какие действия должны быть в таких случаях? Нажимать "тревога" → "сообщить модераторам" и указать причину? Или что?

Comment: 10к+ могут удалять вопросы примерно тем же способом, которым вопросы закрываются.

Comment: @D-side, но непонятно когда появляется кнопка _удалить_. У меня она на некоторых вопросах есть, на некоторых нет

Comment: @Grundy "Чтобы голосовать за удаление вопроса, необходимо подождать 2 дня с момента его закрытия. Это ограничение не распространяется на проверенных пользователей, если рейтинг сообщения -3 или ниже." ([источник](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools))

Answer (score 5):

Ничего делать не надо. Вопрос будет удалён автоматически.

Причина закрытия верная: *«Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой»*.

Стандартный статус `[требует правки]` для вопросов, которые были недавно закрыты, является неудачным именно для этой выбранной причины закрытия.

Учитывая, что причина закрытия может быть ошибочной, в общем случае, не следует лишать автора вопроса стандартной опции: *«Если вопрос можно переформулировать согласно правилам, изложенным в справке, отредактируйте его»*.

Можно добавить в описание выбранной причины закрытия, что **если автор вопроса согласен с этой причиной закрытия**, что это опечатка и вопрос навряд ли поможет будущим посетителям сайта, **то автор может сам удалить вопрос сразу**, не дожидаясь пока это система сделает. См. [Почему и как удаляются некоторые вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: `Учитывая, что причина закрытия может быть ошибочной, в общем случае` - не может, если, как я описал в вопросе - было согласовано с автором это.......`то автор может сам удалить вопрос сразу` - за N-ное количество удалений можно и в бан попасть вроде как. А это не очень приятно.............`Вопрос будет удалён автоматически.` - разве закрытый вопрос удаляется со временем?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: чтобы в бан попасть, человеку придётся много-много опечаток в виде вопросов назадавать. Если это действительно будет проблемой, то можно подкрутить алгоритм, чтобы он игнорировал вопросы, вызванные опечатками—но я не думаю, что это потребуется. То есть достаточно подправить описание, если есть индикация, что люди пытаются редактировать  такие вопросы, даже если они согласны с причиной закрытия.

Answer (score -1):

За, если у ответивших пользователей после удаления вопроса, вызванного опечаткой, сохранится репутация за ответ. [**В текущей редакции правил**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1410/199934) **против**. **Удалениями Stack Overflow запрещает участницам и участникам опечатываться**. Но судя по количеству вопросов, вызванных опечатками, мы, в особенности, новички, продолжаем и будем продолжать опечатываться.

1. У отвечающих не останется мотивации. Смысл тратить своё время на вопрос, зная, что его снесут вместе с ответом, и твоя репутация всё равно не подымется? Как итог, пользовательницы и пользователи вынуждены мучиться с опечатками самостоятельно. В особенности на начальных этапах изучения это может вызвать немало сложностей.
2. Ну, будут висеть закрытые вопросы, вызванные опечатками. Какой вред это нанесёт как Stack Overflow, так и участницам и участникам сообщества? Чем мешают эти вопросы?
3. Да, многие опечатки бесполезны для других пользовательниц и пользователей, но не все. [**Цитата**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1410/199934):

> Однако, вопрос с опечаткой не всегда является бесполезным. Бывают очень популярные ошибки/опечатки, основанные на непонимании фундаментальных вещей. О них новичкам будет полезно почитать.

На мой взгляд, в текущем формате удаления вопросов, вызванных опечатками, противоречат цели взаимопомощи между участницами и участниками на Stack Overflow.

Comment: `У отвечающих не останется мотивации` - количество вопросов с опечатками к остальным очень низок, поэтому говорить о том, что не останется мотивации, по-моему, глупо. Да и вроде мотивация должна быть помощь остальным, а не кармофермерство, не?  `Смысл тратить своё время на вопрос, зная, что его снесут вместе с ответом, и твоя репутация всё равно не подымется` - смысл отвечать на оффтоп? Если человек знает правила, и что ответ на оффтоп бессмысленен, и что вопрос оффтописчный закрывают или удаляют, но все отвечает, то, похоже, отвечающий глуп сам по себе.

Comment: `Однако, вопрос с опечаткой не всегда является бесполезным.` - да, но это скорее не опечатки, о которых речь а вещи  `основанные на непонимании фундаментальных вещей.`. Это разные вещи. Не знать, что в javascript об automatic semicolon insertion и последствиях одно. написать `mySqli()` вместо `mysqli()` совсем другое.

Comment: Про `Чем мешают эти вопросы?` я вообще молчу. Это всё равно что по дому раскидывать обертки от конфет, шоколадок, шкурки колбасы, сосисок, попки огурцов, жить в этом и спрашивать `чем они мешают?`

Comment: `У отвечающих не останется мотивации` — полагал, из контекста будет понятно, что имелась в виду *мотивация отвечать на вопросы, вызванные опечатками*. Видимо, я ошибся. // `Да и вроде мотивация должна быть помощь остальным, а не кармофермерство, не?` — 1) репутация — поощрение за полезный вклад. Не думаю, что на одном альтруизме можно далеко уехать. 2) Почему «должна»? Для Stack Overflow не имеет разницы, написала ли ты ответ с целью набить стату или же из высших побуждений. Важен результат, а не мотивы.

Comment: `смысл отвечать на оффтоп?` — если их сразу удалят, то да, бессмысленно. Но закрытые отвеченные вопросы и ответы на них могут долго висеть, приносить пользу другим. //

`да, но это скорее не опечатки, о которых речь а вещи основанные на непонимании фундаментальных вещей.` — однако эти самые `вещи, основанные на непонимании фундаментальных вещей` ведь тоже будут удаляться.

Comment: `Это всё равно что по дому раскидывать обертки от конфет, шоколадок, шкурки колбасы, сосисок, попки огурцов,` — 1) Раскидывая вышесказанное, в доме появятся членистоногие-паразиты. От вопросов ничего не заведётся. 2) Обёртки и прочее будет попадаться на глаза, тогда как закрытые вопросы нет. Прочие недостатки любого из объектов аналогии? //

Спасибо.

Comment: `репутация — поощрение за полезный вклад. Не думаю, что на одном альтруизме можно далеко уехать` - тем не менее цель у ресурса четко описана, если кто-то не способен помочь просто так - может не задерживаться тут. Никого не держат. Те, кто согласен помогать - придут и помогут.......`однако эти самые вещи, тоже будут удаляться.` - нет. В начале попробуйте понять то, в чем состоит разница и тогда поймете, почему они не будут удаляться.....`От вопросов ничего не заведётся` заведутся новые паразиты, которые думают, что так тут заведено и будут плодить этот мусор, а те, кто уже мусорил - продолжит.

Comment: Вы решили затеять бессмысленный спор? Если вам нравится в грязи валяться, вы можете это делать, но не стоит такое поведение привносить во всех аспектах жизни.

Comment: `репутация — поощрение за полезный вклад` - польза от поиска опечатки или дебага огромной простыни кода ограничена снизу нулём, а сверху - пользой для одного конкретного автора вопроса. Это очень мало по сравнению с более общими вопросами, ответы на которые полезны сотням и тысячам читателей.

Comment: `От вопросов ничего не заведётся` - почитайте про теорию разбитых окон. Плохие вопросы, особенно наплюсованные, незакрытые и с ответами, создают атмосферу, в которой таких вопросов становится только больше.