# Как задать вопрос на не русском https://stackoverflow.com

Tags: поддержка

как задать вопрос на не русском https://stackoverflow.com?

с русским https://RU.stackoverflow.com проблем нет - задаю же этот вопрос.

но когда на на https://stackoverflow.com жму кнопку "Ask Question" перехожу на вот это: [image: screenshot of "how to ask" page]

Comment: что еще раз подтверждает, что надо ЧИТАТЬ, прежде чем задавать вопрос

Comment: если непонятно, то там написано что надо делать, обозначены краткие правила, надо ПРОЧИТАТЬ их, ознакомиться, согласится с ними и нажать proceed после ознакомления

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, странно, что нет rus.SO такого...

Comment: @Air тогда численность вопросов бы сократилась на 90%. Потому что никто не читает, что написано, всем нужно поскорее задать вопрос, а тут такой внезапный блок-читалка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да хотя бы мусора было бы меньше... я тут пару дней назад аж 7 или 8 вопрос тревогой отметил только за один день... На мой взгляд, кому надо, тот будет читать и будет задавать вопросы...  Надо бы сделали тут такое... Я был бы за.. Я сам был таким, 3-4 месяца назад, чего душой кривить, но мне кажется выровнял ситуацию... Меня и блокировали и минусов понаставли...

Comment: спасибо @АлексейШиманский

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Other этот офтоп вообще надо закрыть, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut, быть может, но ответы стоит постить ответом.

Comment: @Other если вопрос не тематичен, ответов у него быть не должно. Переносите на MSO и публикуйте там сколько угодно ответов.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сколько денег готовы поставить, что до 20 вопросов в день [с 200 упадёт](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)(90%). К чему негативные высказывания, к тому же вероятно ложные?  Как это сайту помогает? Нигилизм дёшев и мозгов не требует.

Comment: @alexolut, вопрос есть? Открыт? Ответ в комментах есть? Значит надо нормально оформить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский кому надо поскорее задать вопрос, просто поставит внизу галочку и нажмёт "далее". См. ситуацию с лицензионными соглашениями к ПО. А там "блоки-читалки" побольше будут.

Comment: @D-side чтобы нажать галочку и "далее", нужно ознакомиться с текстом, в котором чудесным образом можно их обнаружить. Но, как можно наблюдать в вопросе,  это непреодолимая преграда ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы давно в последний раз ознакамливались с лицензионным соглашением? :) Вопрос риторически-статистический. Нет, чтобы нажать на галочку, достаточно увидеть галочку в конце простыни текста.

Comment: @D-side о том и речь. что мешало ТС нажать? непреодолимая жажда задать вопрос, а не разбираться что тут подсунули

Comment: @Other т.е. если кто-то ответит в комментах на вопрос "А как мне задать вопрос на Вопросы@почта.рф?" его стоит оформить ответом? Отвечать на оффтоп смысла нет и, вероятно, по этой же причине Алексей написал в комментах, а не в секции ответов.

Comment: @alexolut я на мете вообще не пишу ответы в 99.8% случаев)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот только помимо этих экстремальных случаев у нас много "колеблющихся", которые уже узнали что из себя представляет ресурс из "тура" и хотят узнать, как не накосячить, задавая вопрос; сейчас единственный ресурс для таких у нас -- справка, но она одним своим объёмом здорово демотивирует.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну, это понятно. [Боязнь расстрела](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3984/176217).

Comment: @alexolut все проще - лень

Comment: @АлексейШиманский лень выбрать блок ответа вместо блока комментариев при печати текста? Звучит неубедительно.

Comment: @alexolut в 99.8% случаев надо писать подробно что куда зачем. Это, если взглянуть на любые стандартные лапшевидные ответы с кучей ссылок и воды на мете - 20-30-40 строк. Поэтому да, лень.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так Other утверждает, что имеющегося коммента достаточно.

Comment: @alexolut ну так я и написал в комментарии, все верно :-D

Comment: @alexolut, раз вопрос не расстреляли из ядерной пукалки Экстерминатуса, значит общество считает его достойным существования, а значит и ответов, если есть. Ответы в комментах не приветствуются, если они могут быть полноценным ответом, вот и вся логика моей просьбы.

Comment: Прошу пардону что своим вопросом вызвал такой кипешь.

Comment: По какому поводу терки между уважаемыми джентельменами?

Comment: @Vlad74 задели больную для многих тему - слишком большое количество пользователей не желающих читать. Но бурные обсуждения на мете - это хорошо, не беспокойтесь.

Comment: будущее для ленивых и тупых.

Comment: если модераторы это поймут - будут клиенты, если нет будет песочница с правильными пользователями и ленивыми администраторами.